# How to have multiple colors in a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, colors, character-encoding, cmd

I was wondering if its possible to have different colored text on the same line in a Windows batch file, for example if it says

```
echo hi world
```

I want "hi" to be one color, and "world" to be another color. Maybe I could set the COLOR command as a variable:

```
set color1= color 2
set color9= color A
```

and then deploy them both on the same line along with

```
echo hi world
```

but I don't know how I would do that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Actually this can be done without creating a temporary file.
The method described by jeb and dbenham will work even with a target file that contains no backspaces. The critical point is that the line recognized by findstr.exe must not end with a CRLF.
So the obvious text file to scan with a line not ending with a CRLF is the invoking batch itself, provided that we end it with such a line!
Here's an updated example script working this way...

Changes from the previous example:

- Uses a single dash on the last line as the searchable string. (Must be short and not appear anywhere else like this in the batch.)
- Renamed routines and variables to be a little more object-oriented :-)
- Removed one call level, to slightly improve performance.
- Added comments (Beginning with :# to look more like most other scripting languages.)

---

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :Echo.Color.Init

goto main

:Echo.Color %1=Color %2=Str [%3=/n]
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str=%~2"
:Echo.Color.2
:# Replace path separators in the string, so that the final path still refers to the current path.
set "str=a%ECHO.DEL%!str:\=a%ECHO.DEL%\..\%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%!"
set "str=!str:/=a%ECHO.DEL%/..\%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%!"
set "str=!str:"=\"!"
:# Go to the script directory and search for the trailing -
pushd "%ECHO.DIR%"
findstr /p /r /a:%~1 "^^-" "!str!\..\!ECHO.FILE!" nul
popd
:# Remove the name of this script from the output. (Dependant on its length.)
for /l %%n in (1,1,12) do if not "!ECHO.FILE:~%%n!"=="" <nul set /p "=%ECHO.DEL%"
:# Remove the other unwanted characters "\..\: -"
<nul set /p "=%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%"
:# Append the optional CRLF
if not "%~3"=="" echo.
endlocal & goto :eof

:Echo.Color.Var %1=Color %2=StrVar [%3=/n]
if not defined %~2 goto :eof
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str=!%~2!"
goto :Echo.Color.2

:Echo.Color.Init
set "ECHO.COLOR=call :Echo.Color"
set "ECHO.DIR=%~dp0"
set "ECHO.FILE=%~nx0"
set "ECHO.FULL=%ECHO.DIR%%ECHO.FILE%"
:# Use prompt to store a backspace into a variable. (Actually backspace+space+backspace)
for /F "tokens=1 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "ECHO.DEL=%%a"
goto :eof

:main
call :Echo.Color 0a "a"
call :Echo.Color 0b "b"
set "txt=^" & call :Echo.Color.Var 0c txt
call :Echo.Color 0d "<"
call :Echo.Color 0e ">"
call :Echo.Color 0f "&"
call :Echo.Color 1a "|"
call :Echo.Color 1b " "
call :Echo.Color 1c "%%%%"
call :Echo.Color 1d ^"""
call :Echo.Color 1e "*"
call :Echo.Color 1f "?"
:# call :Echo.Color 2a "!"
call :Echo.Color 2b "."
call :Echo.Color 2c ".."
call :Echo.Color 2d "/"
call :Echo.Color 2e "\"
call :Echo.Color 2f "q:" /n
echo(
set complex="c:\hello world!/.\..\\a//^<%%>&|!" /^^^<%%^>^&^|!\
call :Echo.Color.Var 74 complex /n

exit /b

:# The following line must be last and not end by a CRLF.
-
```

PS. I'm having a problem with the output of the ! character that you did not have in the previous example. (Or at least you did not have the same symptoms.) To be investigated.

Comment: The problem with the `!` can be solved with an `call :Echo.Color 2f ^^^!` or when the delayed expansion is enabled while calling use `call :Echo.Color 2f ^^^^^^^!`

Comment: Hi, perhaps I'm missing something, but I'm using your example above, line-for-line in a command prompt (non-admin) on Win 8.1 Update 1 and I get the following output: http://i.imgur.com/1CsOWdu.png - is that right? Thanks

Comment: Interesting idea, but I would not use this technique because the script name should be descriptive, but the longer the name, the more dead space you have at the end of each line where you cannot print in color. I would always use a file name length 1, but that cannot be descriptive, so I use a temp file.

Comment: There is no need to worry about a unique line. You can simply look for lines that do not contain a CR by using the `/V` option with a search string of `$`. The FINDSTR regex $ anchor looks for CR! Also, there is no need to compute the length of file name each time. That can be done during initialization, and the delete characters can be incorporated into a string "constant".

Answer (score 78):

You can do multicolor outputs without any external programs.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)
echo say the name of the colors, don't read

call :ColorText 0a "blue"
call :ColorText 0C "green"
call :ColorText 0b "red"
echo(
call :ColorText 19 "yellow"
call :ColorText 2F "black"
call :ColorText 4e "white"

goto :eof

:ColorText
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
goto :eof
```

It uses the color feature of the findstr command.

Findstr can be configured to output line numbers or filenames in a defined color.
So I first create a file with the text as filename, and the content is a single `<backspace>` character (ASCII 8).
Then I search all non empty lines in the file and in nul, so the filename will be output in the correct color appended with a colon, but the colon is immediatly removed by the `<backspace>`.

**EDIT: One year later ... all characters are valid**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)

rem Prepare a file "X" with only one dot
<nul > X set /p ".=."

call :color 1a "a"
call :color 1b "b"
call :color 1c "^!<>&| %%%%"*?"
exit /b

:color
set "param=^%~2" !
set "param=!param:"=\"!"
findstr /p /A:%1 "." "!param!\..\X" nul
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
exit /b
```

This uses the rule for valid path/filenames.
If a `\..\` is in the path the prefixed elemet will be removed completly and it's not necessary that this element contains only valid filename characters.

Comment: ok this worked great but is there any way that i can reduce the amount of typing to a single line of code to do this? is it possible for me to set this as a global variable called "defcolor" and be able to use it every time i open the command prompt? (by importing it or having it as a system variable?)

Comment: and could you show me a template that i could use for this? like the template for "findstr" command is something like "FINDSTR /A /File[Filename] /Path[path]" something generic that i can use as a guide for future use.

Comment: This is a creative and interesting solution, however unfortunately it's limited to displaying text characters that are valid in a filename, which can be a showstopper if, for example, you don't have control over the text you want to display (like you are outputting errors from a build log file in red).  It would be great if there was a way around this limitation...

Comment: @Mr. Bungle: But now, also all other characters works too :-)

Comment: I'd give +1, but I had already done so before your edit :)  It still doesn't handle all characters yet. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10407642/1012053

Comment: @dbenham - I knowed that it failed for some characters, I saw the solution, but I was to lazy to solve it :-)

Comment: once it changes color how do i get it to move to a newline?

Comment: To move to a newline just use `echo(`

Comment: You should delete your temp file, before exiting.. `del /f /q X` ;) Very nice solution..

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your work, the second solution works, except from the colon (:) character which generates an error. Also would you mind to explain what the code is doing ? Especially the initializing loop and then the set /p command?

Comment: Works flawlessly on newer OS, but renaming the "X" file to something with longer name (even if compensated by extra %DEL%) and having a single long line of text will print out the name of the temp file at the end of the line on Win Server 2003 and XP based systems.
Doesn't happen if temp file is 1 character long or if lines of text are relatively short. (maybe ~50symbols)

Comment: @jeb I made a big edit to yours. I hope, you don't mind it being big. It was just that some people were requesting a simple way to do it.

Comment: @jeb. Brilliant! I do observe that it works fine as long as string to display is 72 characters or less. If string is 73 characters or more the rest of the line (out to 80 columns) contains as much of the string "\..\X:." as will fit in 80 columns.

Comment: @RGuggisberg Yes for the XP compatible version, the line ends with `\..\X:.`. These 7 characters are deleted, but when the line is too long and wraps they can't be deleted anymore. I suppose for XP this can't be solved, but the first solution shows a way to solve it for Win7 and later

Comment: @jeb, Ok, I see, but I like the second one. First one does not print dot (period) if it is last character. Second one also allows use of * and first one does not. Think I will use 2nd one and restrict line length. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent -you could insert `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` as the first line of the subroutine and it would then not require delayed expansion in the caller. I'd change the name since `color` is a keyword in batch and for obvious reasons it doesn't like `/` or `\`. Nevertheless, brilliant.

Comment: Sorry for digging this thread back up, but for some weird reason `!` does not work when using the `call` function. It seems to work with `echo`, however. `call :colorEcho C "# ALERT: You have lost 5 Health Points^^^! You are now at %Health% HP^^^!"` I've tried different combinations of `^`, but it still would not work.

Comment: You can't escape an exclamation mark (no always) when used as call parameter, but please open a new question for this

Comment: See my (now rejected) suggested edit, to make it neater not having a file left at the folder. The link: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13561046#

Comment: This is not working when I put this function in another file, and call it from a script running as admin. It adds a `^` character to the beginning. (This only happens in Windows 10).

Comment: @MarkDodsons You should ask a new question with your code, this can't be solved in the comment section

Comment: @jeb I did so here https://superuser.com/questions/1353777/this-script-will-not-work-when-running-as-admin?noredirect=1#comment2030854_1353777

Comment: the above fails if the string contains a backslash followed by another character ie: call :color 1c "^!<>&| %%%%"*?\a"

Comment: Thank you for the code. It's working. But creating a temporary file for each colored echo really sucks. Someone should write a C/C++ program which does the job.

Comment: I like this approach but there are a few small issues with this solution (talking about the "one year later" one), e.g. the X file removal. I proposed my solution as a separate answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-windows-batch-file/77799267#77799267

Answer (score 46):

jeb's edited answer comes close to solving all the issues. But it has problems with the following strings:

```
"a\b\"
"a/b/"
"\"
"/"
"."
".."
"c:"
```

I've modified his technique to something that I think can truly handle any string of printable characters, except for length limitations.

Other improvements:

- Uses the %TEMP% location for the temp file, so no longer need write access to the current directory.
- Created 2 variants, one takes a string literal, the other the name of a variable containing the string. The variable version is generally less convenient, but it eliminates some special character escape issues.
- Added the /n option as an optional 3rd parameter to append a newline at the end of the output.

Backspace does not work across a line break, so the technique can have problems if the line wraps. For example, printing a string with length between 74 - 79 will not work properly if the console has a line width of 80.

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :initColorPrint

call :colorPrint 0a "a"
call :colorPrint 0b "b"
set "txt=^" & call :colorPrintVar 0c txt
call :colorPrint 0d "<"
call :colorPrint 0e ">"
call :colorPrint 0f "&"
call :colorPrint 1a "|"
call :colorPrint 1b " "
call :colorPrint 1c "%%%%"
call :colorPrint 1d ^"""
call :colorPrint 1e "*"
call :colorPrint 1f "?"
call :colorPrint 2a "!"
call :colorPrint 2b "."
call :colorPrint 2c ".."
call :colorPrint 2d "/"
call :colorPrint 2e "\"
call :colorPrint 2f "q:" /n
echo(
set complex="c:\hello world!/.\..\\a//^<%%>&|!" /^^^<%%^>^&^|!\
call :colorPrintVar 74 complex /n

call :cleanupColorPrint

exit /b

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:colorPrint Color  Str  [/n]
setlocal
set "str=%~2"
call :colorPrintVar %1 str %3
exit /b

:colorPrintVar  Color  StrVar  [/n]
if not defined %~2 exit /b
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str=a%DEL%!%~2:\=a%DEL%\..\%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%!"
set "str=!str:/=a%DEL%/..\%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%!"
set "str=!str:"=\"!"
pushd "%temp%"
findstr /p /A:%1 "." "!str!\..\x" nul
if /i "%~3"=="/n" echo(
exit /b

:initColorPrint
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "DEL=%%a"
<nul >"%temp%\x" set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%.%DEL%"
exit /b

:cleanupColorPrint
del "%temp%\x"
exit /b
```

***UPDATE 2012-11-27***

*This method fails on XP because FINDSTR displays backspace as a period on the screen. jeb's original answer works on XP, albeit with the limitations already noted*

***UPDATE 2012-12-14***

There has been a lot of development activity at [DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4014) and [SS64](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=6334). It turns out that FINDSTR also corrupts file names containing extended ASCII if supplied on the command line. I've updated my [FINDSTR Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053).

Below is a version that works on XP and supports ALL single byte characters except 0x00 (nul), 0x0A (linefeed), and 0x0D (carriage return). However, when running on XP, most control characters will display as dots. This is an inherent feature of FINDSTR on XP that cannot be avoided.

Unfortunately, adding support for XP and for extended ASCII characters slows the routine down :-(

Just for fun, I grabbed some color ASCII art from [joan stark's ASCII Art Gallery](http://www.oocities.org/spunk1111/) and adapted it for use with ColorPrint. I added a :c entry point just for shorthand, and to handle an issue with quote literals.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set q=^"
echo(
echo(
call :c 0E "                ,      .-;" /n
call :c 0E "             ,  |\    / /  __," /n
call :c 0E "             |\ '.`-.|  |.'.-'" /n
call :c 0E "              \`'-:  `; : /" /n
call :c 0E "               `-._'.  \'|" /n
call :c 0E "              ,_.-=` ` `  ~,_" /n
call :c 0E "               '--,.    "&call :c 0c ".-. "&call :c 0E ",=!q!." /n
call :c 0E "                 /     "&call :c 0c "{ "&call :c 0A "* "&call :c 0c ")"&call :c 0E "`"&call :c 06 ";-."&call :c 0E "}" /n
call :c 0E "                 |      "&call :c 0c "'-' "&call :c 06 "/__ |" /n
call :c 0E "                 /          "&call :c 06 "\_,\|" /n
call :c 0E "                 |          (" /n
call :c 0E "             "&call :c 0c "__ "&call :c 0E "/ '          \" /n
call :c 02 "     /\_    "&call :c 0c "/,'`"&call :c 0E "|     '   "&call :c 0c ".-~!q!~~-." /n
call :c 02 "     |`.\_ "&call :c 0c "|   "&call :c 0E "/  ' ,    "&call :c 0c "/        \" /n
call :c 02 "   _/  `, \"&call :c 0c "|  "&call :c 0E "; ,     . "&call :c 0c "|  ,  '  . |" /n
call :c 02 "   \   `,  "&call :c 0c "|  "&call :c 0E "|  ,  ,   "&call :c 0c "|  :  ;  : |" /n
call :c 02 "   _\  `,  "&call :c 0c "\  "&call :c 0E "|.     ,  "&call :c 0c "|  |  |  | |" /n
call :c 02 "   \`  `.   "&call :c 0c "\ "&call :c 0E "|   '     "&call :c 0A "|"&call :c 0c "\_|-'|_,'\|" /n
call :c 02 "   _\   `,   "&call :c 0A "`"&call :c 0E "\  '  . ' "&call :c 0A "| |  | |  |           "&call :c 02 "__" /n
call :c 02 "   \     `,   "&call :c 0E "| ,  '    "&call :c 0A "|_/'-|_\_/     "&call :c 02 "__ ,-;` /" /n
call :c 02 "    \    `,    "&call :c 0E "\ .  , ' .| | | | |   "&call :c 02 "_/' ` _=`|" /n
call :c 02 "     `\    `,   "&call :c 0E "\     ,  | | | | |"&call :c 02 "_/'   .=!q!  /" /n
call :c 02 "     \`     `,   "&call :c 0E "`\      \/|,| ;"&call :c 02 "/'   .=!q!    |" /n
call :c 02 "      \      `,    "&call :c 0E "`\' ,  | ; "&call :c 02 "/'    =!q!    _/" /n
call :c 02 "       `\     `,  "&call :c 05 ".-!q!!q!-. "&call :c 0E "': "&call :c 02 "/'    =!q!     /" /n
call :c 02 "    jgs _`\    ;"&call :c 05 "_{  '   ; "&call :c 02 "/'    =!q!      /" /n
call :c 02 "       _\`-/__"&call :c 05 ".~  `."&call :c 07 "8"&call :c 05 ".'.!q!`~-. "&call :c 02 "=!q!     _,/" /n
call :c 02 "    __\      "&call :c 05 "{   '-."&call :c 07 "|"&call :c 05 ".'.--~'`}"&call :c 02 "    _/" /n
call :c 02 "    \    .=!q!` "&call :c 05 "}.-~!q!'"&call :c 0D "u"&call :c 05 "'-. '-..'  "&call :c 02 "__/" /n
call :c 02 "   _/  .!q!    "&call :c 05 "{  -'.~('-._,.'"&call :c 02 "\_,/" /n
call :c 02 "  /  .!q!    _/'"&call :c 05 "`--; ;  `.  ;" /n
call :c 02 "   .=!q!  _/'      "&call :c 05 "`-..__,-'" /n
call :c 02 "    __/'" /n
echo(

exit /b

:c
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:colorPrint Color  Str  [/n]
setlocal
set "s=%~2"
call :colorPrintVar %1 s %3
exit /b

:colorPrintVar  Color  StrVar  [/n]
if not defined DEL call :initColorPrint
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
pushd .
':
cd \
set "s=!%~2!"
:: The single blank line within the following IN() clause is critical - DO NOT REMOVE
for %%n in (^"^

^") do (
  set "s=!s:\=%%~n\%%~n!"
  set "s=!s:/=%%~n/%%~n!"
  set "s=!s::=%%~n:%%~n!"
)
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%s in ("!s!") do (
  if "!" equ "" setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
  if %%s==\ (
    findstr /a:%~1 "." "\'" nul
    <nul set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
  ) else if %%s==/ (
    findstr /a:%~1 "." "/.\'" nul
    <nul set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
  ) else (
    >colorPrint.txt (echo %%s\..\')
    findstr /a:%~1 /f:colorPrint.txt "."
    <nul set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
  )
)
if /i "%~3"=="/n" echo(
popd
exit /b


:initColorPrint
for /f %%A in ('"prompt $H&for %%B in (1) do rem"') do set "DEL=%%A %%A"
<nul >"%temp%\'" set /p "=."
subst ': "%temp%" >nul
exit /b


:cleanupColorPrint
2>nul del "%temp%\'"
2>nul del "%temp%\colorPrint.txt"
>nul subst ': /d
exit /b
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this script handles those characters used to make dos-like menus? [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character)

Comment: @Elieder - Have you tried? It should work, but you need to get the appropriate extended ASCII codes in a variable, and your active code page must be set appropriately. Ask a new question if you can't get it to work.

Comment: I'm running into an issue where I want '## %76 space% ##' to be displayed, however its showing up like '##      \.##' I have no idea why, belowe is my code: 'call :c 0e "##"&call :c f9 "%76 Spaces%"&call :c 0a "##"'

Comment: Seems like the foreign characters that are showing up are \..\':.

and they show up on each line (Which is hidden because my content is 80 chr, and my window frame is 80chr

Comment: @level42 - The window width must be a bit wider than the longest line because it writes unwanted characters and then uses backspace to erase them. If it writes past the screen width, then the backspace is not able to erase them anymore.

Comment: Really! Awe, I was hoping to have a "Splash Screen" that was boxed in ## characters. It seems to work fine on all lines, except for 2 (of ~15)

Comment: That certainly did work on XP. Amazing command line contortions here! And pretty demo. Awesome.

Comment: @SubhamTripathi - Explanations have already been given - Read [jeb's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5344911/1012053), and also follow the links in my answer.

Comment: @dbenham This suddenly stopped working for me, it is now giving me this error in all my batch files. I havn't done anything to the files... Any ideas what's going on? https://s19.postimg.cc/9rq9wfm37/screenshot_2018_06_22_at_10_31_45.png

Comment: To address the speed problem and characters problem, i suggest here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66604485/3641635) an alternative way. Maybe that could interest @jeb too.

Answer (score 15):

If you have a modern Windows (that has powershell installed), the following may work fine as well

```
call :PrintBright Something Something

  (do actual batch stuff here)

call :PrintBright Done!
goto :eof


:PrintBright
powershell -Command Write-Host "%*" -foreground "White"
```

Adjust the color as you see fit.

Comment: Good idea.  I [expanded on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27322578/1683264).

Answer (score 7):

[Without external tools](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/coloroutput.bat).This is a self-compiled **bat/.net hybrid** (should be saved as `.BAT`) that can be used on any system that have installed .net framework  (it's a rare thing to see an windows without .NET framework even for the oldest XP/2003 installations) . It uses jscript.net compiler to create an exe capable to print strings with different background/foreground color only for the current line.

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:-d  /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\*jsc.exe"') do (
   set "jsc=%%v"
)

if not exist "%~n0.exe" (
    "%jsc%" /nologo /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0"
)

%~n0.exe %*

endlocal & exit /b %errorlevel%

*/

import System;

var arguments:String[] = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

var newLine = false;
var output = "";
var foregroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
var backgroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor;
var evaluate = false;
var currentBackground=Console.BackgroundColor;
var currentForeground=Console.ForegroundColor;


//http://stackoverflow.com/a/24294348/388389
var jsEscapes = {
  'n': '\n',
  'r': '\r',
  't': '\t',
  'f': '\f',
  'v': '\v',
  'b': '\b'
};

function decodeJsEscape(_, hex0, hex1, octal, other) {
  var hex = hex0 || hex1;
  if (hex) { return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex, 16)); }
  if (octal) { return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(octal, 8)); }
  return jsEscapes[other] || other;
}

function decodeJsString(s) {
  return s.replace(
      // Matches an escape sequence with UTF-16 in group 1, single byte hex in group 2,
      // octal in group 3, and arbitrary other single-character escapes in group 4.
      /\\(?:u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})|x([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})|([0-3][0-7]{0,2}|[4-7][0-7]?)|(.))/g,
      decodeJsEscape);
}


function printHelp( ) {
   print( arguments[0] + "  -s string [-f foreground] [-b background] [-n] [-e]" );
   print( " " );
   print( " string          String to be printed" );
   print( " foreground      Foreground color - a " );
   print( "                 number between 0 and 15." );
   print( " background      Background color - a " );
   print( "                 number between 0 and 15." );
   print( " -n              Indicates if a new line should" );
   print( "                 be written at the end of the ");
   print( "                 string(by default - no)." );
   print( " -e              Evaluates special character " );
   print( "                 sequences like \\n\\b\\r and etc ");
   print( "" );
   print( "Colors :" );
   for ( var c = 0 ; c < 16 ; c++ ) {

        Console.BackgroundColor = c;
        Console.Write( " " );
        Console.BackgroundColor=currentBackground;
        Console.Write( "-"+c );
        Console.WriteLine( "" );
   }
   Console.BackgroundColor=currentBackground;



}

function errorChecker( e:Error ) {
        if ( e.message == "Input string was not in a correct format." ) {
            print( "the color parameters should be numbers between 0 and 15" );
            Environment.Exit( 1 );
        } else if (e.message == "Index was outside the bounds of the array.") {
            print( "invalid arguments" );
            Environment.Exit( 2 );
        } else {
            print ( "Error Message: " + e.message );
            print ( "Error Code: " + ( e.number & 0xFFFF ) );
            print ( "Error Name: " + e.name );
            Environment.Exit( 666 );
        }
}

function numberChecker( i:Int32 ){
    if( i > 15 || i < 0 ) {
        print("the color parameters should be numbers between 0 and 15");
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
}


if ( arguments.length == 1 || arguments[1].toLowerCase() == "-help" || arguments[1].toLowerCase() == "-help"   ) {
    printHelp();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}

for (var arg = 1; arg <= arguments.length-1; arg++ ) {
    if ( arguments[arg].toLowerCase() == "-n" ) {
        newLine=true;
    }

    if ( arguments[arg].toLowerCase() == "-e" ) {
        evaluate=true;
    }

    if ( arguments[arg].toLowerCase() == "-s" ) {
        output=arguments[arg+1];
    }


    if ( arguments[arg].toLowerCase() == "-b" ) {

        try {
            backgroundColor=Int32.Parse( arguments[arg+1] );
        } catch(e) {
            errorChecker(e);
        }
    }

    if ( arguments[arg].toLowerCase() == "-f" ) {
        try {
            foregroundColor=Int32.Parse(arguments[arg+1]);
        } catch(e) {
            errorChecker(e);
        }
    }
}

Console.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor ;
Console.ForegroundColor = foregroundColor ;

if ( evaluate ) {
    output=decodeJsString(output);
}

if ( newLine ) {
    Console.WriteLine(output);  
} else {
    Console.Write(output);

}

Console.BackgroundColor = currentBackground;
Console.ForegroundColor = currentForeground;
```

Example `coloroutput.bat  -s "aa\nbb\n\u0025cc" -b 10 -f 3 -n -e`

You can also check carlos' color function -> http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4453

Answer (score 7):

Combining [dbenham's bird and syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407642/1683264) with [skrebbel's powershell `write-host` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12894047/1683264), it seems that powershell can render complex art more quickly than dbenham's pure batch method (well, after powershell has been primed once, anyway).  Minimal massaging of the strings are needed, although I haven't tested this with anything other than the bird.  If you want a bright green end-of-transmission character for example, you may be out of luck.  **<kbd>:)</kbd>**

This method requires echoing out to a temp file, simply because invoking powershell for each `call :c` takes forever, and it's much faster to queue the output for one powershell invocation.  But it does have the advantage of simplicity and efficiency.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set q=^"
echo(
echo(
call :c 0E "                ,      .-;" /n
call :c 0E "             ,  |\    / /  __," /n
call :c 0E "             |\ '.`-.|  |.'.-'" /n
call :c 0E "              \`'-:  `; : /" /n
call :c 0E "               `-._'.  \'|" /n
call :c 0E "              ,_.-=` ` `  ~,_" /n
call :c 0E "               '--,.    "&call :c 0c ".-. "&call :c 0E ",=!q!." /n
call :c 0E "                 /     "&call :c 0c "{ "&call :c 0A "* "&call :c 0c ")"&call :c 0E "`"&call :c 06 ";-."&call :c 0E "}" /n
call :c 0E "                 |      "&call :c 0c "'-' "&call :c 06 "/__ |" /n
call :c 0E "                 /          "&call :c 06 "\_,\|" /n
call :c 0E "                 |          (" /n
call :c 0E "             "&call :c 0c "__ "&call :c 0E "/ '          \" /n
call :c 02 "     /\_    "&call :c 0c "/,'`"&call :c 0E "|     '   "&call :c 0c ".-~!q!~~-." /n
call :c 02 "     |`.\_ "&call :c 0c "|   "&call :c 0E "/  ' ,    "&call :c 0c "/        \" /n
call :c 02 "   _/  `, \"&call :c 0c "|  "&call :c 0E "; ,     . "&call :c 0c "|  ,  '  . |" /n
call :c 02 "   \   `,  "&call :c 0c "|  "&call :c 0E "|  ,  ,   "&call :c 0c "|  :  ;  : |" /n
call :c 02 "   _\  `,  "&call :c 0c "\  "&call :c 0E "|.     ,  "&call :c 0c "|  |  |  | |" /n
call :c 02 "   \`  `.   "&call :c 0c "\ "&call :c 0E "|   '     "&call :c 0A "|"&call :c 0c "\_|-'|_,'\|" /n
call :c 02 "   _\   `,   "&call :c 0A "`"&call :c 0E "\  '  . ' "&call :c 0A "| |  | |  |           "&call :c 02 "__" /n
call :c 02 "   \     `,   "&call :c 0E "| ,  '    "&call :c 0A "|_/'-|_\_/     "&call :c 02 "__ ,-;` /" /n
call :c 02 "    \    `,    "&call :c 0E "\ .  , ' .| | | | |   "&call :c 02 "_/' ` _=`|" /n
call :c 02 "     `\    `,   "&call :c 0E "\     ,  | | | | |"&call :c 02 "_/'   .=!q!  /" /n
call :c 02 "     \`     `,   "&call :c 0E "`\      \/|,| ;"&call :c 02 "/'   .=!q!    |" /n
call :c 02 "      \      `,    "&call :c 0E "`\' ,  | ; "&call :c 02 "/'    =!q!    _/" /n
call :c 02 "       `\     `,  "&call :c 05 ".-!q!!q!-. "&call :c 0E "': "&call :c 02 "/'    =!q!     /" /n
call :c 02 "    jgs _`\    ;"&call :c 05 "_{  '   ; "&call :c 02 "/'    =!q!      /" /n
call :c 02 "       _\`-/__"&call :c 05 ".~  `."&call :c 07 "8"&call :c 05 ".'.!q!`~-. "&call :c 02 "=!q!     _,/" /n
call :c 02 "    __\      "&call :c 05 "{   '-."&call :c 07 "|"&call :c 05 ".'.--~'`}"&call :c 02 "    _/" /n
call :c 02 "    \    .=!q!` "&call :c 05 "}.-~!q!'"&call :c 0D "u"&call :c 05 "'-. '-..'  "&call :c 02 "__/" /n
call :c 02 "   _/  .!q!    "&call :c 05 "{  -'.~('-._,.'"&call :c 02 "\_,/" /n
call :c 02 "  /  .!q!    _/'"&call :c 05 "`--; ;  `.  ;" /n
call :c 02 "   .=!q!  _/'      "&call :c 05 "`-..__,-'" /n
call :c 02 "    __/'" /n

if exist "%temp%\color.psm1" (
    powershell -command "&{set-executionpolicy remotesigned; Import-Module '%temp%\color.psm1'}"
    del "%temp%\color.psm1"
)

echo(

exit /b

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:c <color pair> <string> </n>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "colors=0-black;1-darkblue;2-darkgreen;3-darkcyan;4-darkred;5-darkmagenta;6-darkyellow;7-gray;8-darkgray;9-blue;a-green;b-cyan;c-red;d-magenta;e-yellow;f-white"
set "p=%~1"
set "bg=!colors:*%p:~0,1%-=!"
set bg=%bg:;=&rem.%
set "fg=!colors:*%p:~-1%-=!"
set fg=%fg:;=&rem.%

if not "%~3"=="/n" set "br=-nonewline"
set "str=%~2" & set "str=!str:'=''!"

>>"%temp%\color.psm1" echo write-host '!str!' -foregroundcolor '%fg%' -backgroundcolor '%bg%' %br%
endlocal
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible with [**cmdcolor**](https://github.com/jeremejevs/cmdcolor):

```
echo \033[32mhi \033[92mworld
```

`hi` will be dark green, and `world` - light green.

Comment: this one is pretty fast compared to the pure batch solution. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 ((Version 1511, build 10586, release 2015-11-10)) supports [ANSI colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).
You can use the escape key to trigger the color codes.

In the Command Prompt:

```
echo ^[[32m HI ^[[0m
```

echo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>`[32m HI` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>`[0m`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

When using a text editor, you can use ALT key codes.
The ESC key code can be created using <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>NUMPAD</kbd> numbers : <kbd>Alt</kbd>+`027`

```
[32m  HI  [0m
```

Answer (score 3):

*I'll give you the answer you're looking for first, for those who don't want to read a bunch of explanations.*

use [ANSI_escape_code.SGR_parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR_parameters)

```
@echo off 
echo [38;2;255;255;0mHi[m [38;2;128;128;255mWorld[m 
pause > nul
```

> Do not forget input [ESC](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%1B)<sup>0x1B (Hex), \033 (Oct), 27(Dec)</sup> [Virtual-Key Codes VK_ESCAPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes)

I suggest you copy (in case you are missing the ESC key) the above contents, and then paste it on the [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or others IDE you like.

output as below picture

[image]

### Explanation

according [ANSI_escape_code.SGR_parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR_parameters) you know

| Number | Name | Note | Example |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Reset or normal | All attributes off | `ESC[0m` or `ESC[m` |
| 1 | **B**old or increased intensity |  | `ESC[1m` |
| 3 | **I**talic |  | `ESC[3m` |
| 4 | **U**nderline |  | `ESC[4m` |
| 8 | Conceal or **hide** | **Not widely supported.** | `ESC[8m` |
| 30–37 | Set foreground color | 30:black 31: red, 32: green, 33: yellow, 34: blue, 35: purple, 36: Aqua, 37: white | red: `ESC[31m` |
| 38 | Set **foreground** color | Next arguments are 5;n or **2;r;g;b** | red: `ESC[38m;2;255;0;0m` |
| 40–47 | Set background color |  | red: ESC[41m |
| 48 | Set **background** color | Next arguments are 5;n or **2;r;g;b** | red: `ESC[48m;2;255;0;0m` |

*Of course, there are many more you can go to see.*

for example,

| Fake code | code (copy this to try by yourself) | demo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `ESC[31mESC[4mfore color: red and style:underlineESC[0m` | `echo [31m[4mfore color: red and style:underline[0m` | [image: fore-color:red and underline] |

```
ESC[31mESC[4mfore color: red and style:underlineESC[0m
  |       |                 |                   ------  Reset, such that the next one will not apply.
  |       |  -----------------------------------
  |       |   input message      
  |       |
  |    ------ 
  |     Underline
  |
-------
 Set foreground color 31 is red
```

where ESC = 0x1B (since typing ESC in here, the user can't see it.)

### Script and Exercises

```sh
@echo off

:: demo: foreground color
for /l %%x in (30, 1, 37) do (
   call :demoDefaultColor "COLOR" %%x
)

:: demo: background color
for /l %%x in (40, 1, 47) do (
   call :demoDefaultColor "COLOR" %%x
)

call :echoWithColor "Hello world!" 255 0 0
echo Hello world!
call :echoWithColor "Hello world!" 255 0 255  255 255 0

pause > nul
EXIT /B


:demoDefaultColor <msg> <colorFlag>
    echo [%2m%~1[0m
    EXIT /B

:echoWithColor <msg> <fr> <fg> <fb> <br> <bg> <bb>
    SET msg=%~1
    SET fr=%2
    SET fg=%3
    SET fb=%4
    SET br=%5
    SET bg=%6
    SET bb=%7

    echo [48;2;%br%;%bg%;%bb%m[38;2;%fr%;%fg%;%fb%m%msg%[0m
    EXIT /B
```

output:

[image]

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62771672/9935654

Answer (score 2):

Several methods are covered in
"51} How can I echo lines in different colors in NT scripts?"
http://www.netikka.net/tsneti/info/tscmd051.htm

One of the alternatives: If you can get hold of QBASIC, using colors is relatively easy:

```
  @echo off & setlocal enableextensions
  for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ("%temp%") do set temp_=%%~sf
  set skip=
  findstr "'%skip%QB" "%~f0" > %temp_%\tmp$$$.bas
  qbasic /run %temp_%\tmp$$$.bas
  for %%f in (%temp_%\tmp$$$.bas) do if exist %%f del %%f
  endlocal & goto :EOF
  ::
  CLS 'QB
  COLOR 14,0 'QB
  PRINT "A simple "; 'QB
  COLOR 13,0 'QB
  PRINT "color "; 'QB
  COLOR 14,0 'QB
  PRINT "demonstration" 'QB
  PRINT "By Prof. (emer.) Timo Salmi" 'QB
  PRINT 'QB
  FOR j = 0 TO 7 'QB
    FOR i = 0 TO 15 'QB
      COLOR i, j 'QB
      PRINT LTRIM$(STR$(i)); " "; LTRIM$(STR$(j)); 'QB
      COLOR 1, 0 'QB
      PRINT " "; 'QB
    NEXT i 'QB
    PRINT 'QB
  NEXT j 'QB
  SYSTEM 'QB
```

Comment: I suppose QBasic isn't installed on any _modern_ windows version since XP

Comment: Old utilities are still available on the net in packages such as http://download.microsoft.com/download/win95upg/tool_s/1.0/W95/EN-US/olddos.exe

Answer (score 2):

If your console supports ANSI colour codes (e.g. [ConEmu](http://conemu.github.io/), [Clink](https://github.com/mridgers/clink) or [ANSICON](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon)) you can do this:

```
SET    GRAY=%ESC%[0m
SET     RED=%ESC%[1;31m
SET   GREEN=%ESC%[1;32m
SET  ORANGE=%ESC%[0;33m
SET    BLUE=%ESC%[0;34m
SET MAGENTA=%ESC%[0;35m
SET    CYAN=%ESC%[1;36m
SET   WHITE=%ESC%[1;37m
```

where ESC variable contains ASCII character 27.

I found a way to populate the ESC variable here: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=6827#p6827
and using `tasklist` it's possible to test what DLLs are loaded into a process.

The following script gets the process ID of the cmd.exe that the script is running in. Checks if it has a dll that will add ANSI support injected, and then sets colour variables to contain escape sequences or be empty depending on whether colour is supported or not.

```
@echo off

call :INIT_COLORS

echo %RED%RED %GREEN%GREEN %ORANGE%ORANGE %BLUE%BLUE %MAGENTA%MAGENTA %CYAN%CYAN %WHITE%WHITE %GRAY%GRAY

:: pause if double clicked on instead of run from command line.
SET interactive=0
ECHO %CMDCMDLINE% | FINDSTR /L %COMSPEC% >NUL 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 SET interactive=1
@rem ECHO %CMDCMDLINE% %COMSPEC% %interactive%
IF "%interactive%"=="1" PAUSE
EXIT /B 0
Goto :EOF

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
: SUBROUTINES                                                          :
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:INIT_COLORS
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

call :supportsANSI
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  SET GREEN=
  SET RED=
  SET GRAY=
  SET WHITE=
  SET ORANGE=
  SET CYAN=
) ELSE (

  :: If you can, insert ASCII CHAR 27 after equals and remove BL.String.CreateDEL_ESC routine
  set "ESC="
  :: use this if can't type ESC CHAR, it's more verbose, but you can copy and paste it
  call :BL.String.CreateDEL_ESC

  SET    GRAY=%ESC%[0m
  SET     RED=%ESC%[1;31m
  SET   GREEN=%ESC%[1;32m
  SET  ORANGE=%ESC%[0;33m
  SET    BLUE=%ESC%[0;34m
  SET MAGENTA=%ESC%[0;35m
  SET    CYAN=%ESC%[1;36m
  SET   WHITE=%ESC%[1;37m
)

exit /b

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:BL.String.CreateDEL_ESC
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1733
::
:: Creates two variables with one character DEL=Ascii-08 and ESC=Ascii-27
:: DEL and ESC can be used  with and without DelayedExpansion
setlocal
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  ENDLOCAL
  set "DEL=%%a"
  set "ESC=%%b"
  goto :EOF
)

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:supportsANSI
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: returns ERRORLEVEL 0 - YES, 1 - NO
::
:: - Tests for ConEmu, ANSICON and Clink
:: - Returns 1 - NO support, when called via "CMD /D" (i.e. no autoruns / DLL injection)
::   on a system that would otherwise support ANSI.

if "%ConEmuANSI%" == "ON" exit /b 0

call :getPID PID

setlocal

for /f usebackq^ delims^=^"^ tokens^=^* %%a in (`tasklist /fi "PID eq %PID%" /m /fo CSV`) do set "MODULES=%%a"

set MODULES=%MODULES:"=%
set NON_ANSI_MODULES=%MODULES%

:: strip out ANSI dlls from module list:
:: ANSICON adds ANSI64.dll or ANSI32.dll
set "NON_ANSI_MODULES=%NON_ANSI_MODULES:ANSI=%"
:: ConEmu attaches ConEmuHk but ConEmu also sets ConEmuANSI Environment VAR
:: so we've already checked for that above and returned early.
@rem set "NON_ANSI_MODULES=%NON_ANSI_MODULES:ConEmuHk=%"
:: Clink supports ANSI https://github.com/mridgers/clink/issues/54
set "NON_ANSI_MODULES=%NON_ANSI_MODULES:clink_dll=%"

if "%MODULES%" == "%NON_ANSI_MODULES%" endlocal & exit /b 1
endlocal

exit /b 0

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:getPID  [RtnVar]
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: REQUIREMENTS:
::
:: Determine the Process ID of the currently executing script,
:: but in a way that is multiple execution safe especially when the script can be executing multiple times
::   - at the exact same time in the same millisecond,
::   - by multiple users,
::   - in multiple window sessions (RDP),
::   - by privileged and non-privileged (e.g. Administrator) accounts,
::   - interactively or in the background.
::   - work when the cmd.exe window cannot appear
::     e.g. running from TaskScheduler as LOCAL SERVICE or using the "Run whether user is logged on or not" setting
::
:: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/270f0842-963d-4ed9-b27d-27957628004c/what-is-the-pid-of-the-current-cmdexe?forum=msbuild
::
:: http://serverfault.com/a/654029/306
::
:: Store the Process ID (PID) of the currently running script in environment variable RtnVar.
:: If called without any argument, then simply write the PID to stdout.
::
::
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
:getLock
set "lock=%temp%\%~nx0.%time::=.%.lock"
set "uid=%lock:\=:b%"
set "uid=%uid:,=:c%"
set "uid=%uid:'=:q%"
set "uid=%uid:_=:u%"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "uid=!uid:%%=:p!"
endlocal & set "uid=%uid%"
2>nul ( 9>"%lock%" (
  for /f "skip=1" %%A in (
    'wmic process where "name='cmd.exe' and CommandLine like '%%<%uid%>%%'" get ParentProcessID'
  ) do for %%B in (%%A) do set "PID=%%B"
  (call )
))||goto :getLock
del "%lock%" 2>nul
endlocal & if "%~1" equ "" (echo(%PID%) else set "%~1=%PID%"
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

You should download chgcolor.zip from 
http://www.mailsend-online.com/blog/setting-text-color-in-a-batch-file.html
and also download echoj.zip from
www.mailsend-online.com/blog/?p=41
They're both towards the bottom of the page.
Extract both folders to the desktop
and copy the executables(.exe files) from inside the extracted folders to the C:\Windows directory. This will allow them to be executed from the command line.
Open up notepad and copy the following into it:

> @echo off
>
> chgcolor 03
>
> echoj "hi "
>
> chgcolor 0d
>
> echoj "world"
>
> chgcolor 07
>
> echoj $0a

Save the file to the Desktop as hi.bat. Now open the command prompt and navigate to your Desktop folder and type "hi.bat" without the quotes. That should get you started besure to read both webpages to get a full tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

A macro solution for [virtual terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) code usage for windows 10 users

For windows 10 users, it is the fastest method outside of using VT sequences directly while of being more readable.

```
::: Author T3RRY : Created 09/04/2021 : Version 1.0.7
::: Version changes:
::: - ADDED /A switch to allow absolute Y;X value to be supplied as a single switch subarg
::: - ADDED /@ switch to allow saving of cursor position. Subarg allows custom return var to store multiple positions.
::: - ADDED random subarg for /C color switch.
::: - ADDED optional companion switch to /C - '/B'
:::  - When /C random subarg is used, /B may be used with any ONE of the following: R G B C M Y
:::    to bias the output color towards Red Green Blue Cyan Magenta or Yellow
::: - ADDED support for switches with common prefix.
::: - ADDED /T timeout switch for subsecond delays
::: - CORRECTED Switch validation method to handle Switches at EOL with no subargs
::: - ADDED /E Switch to allow /C value to be preserved or Color to be changed at EOL with an integer subarg.
::: - Support REMOVED for switch usage pattern /Switch:value
:::
::: Purpose      : Color and cursor position macro for windows 10 batch files
::: - Allows rapid display of colored output at specified screen position.
:::   For more information, read the usage.
:::
::: Uses macro parameter and switch handling template.
:::  - See :  https://pastebin.com/gzL7AYpC

@Echo off

:# Windows Version control. Assigns flag true if system is windows 10.
 Set "Win10="
 Ver | Findstr /LIC:" 10." > nul && Set "Win10=true"

:# Test if virtual terminal codes enabled ; enable if false
:# removes win10 flag definition if version does not support Virtual Terminal sequences
 If defined Win10 (
  Reg Query HKCU\Console | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LIC:"VirtualTerminalLevel    REG_DWORD    0x1" > nul || (
    Reg Add HKCU\Console /f /v VirtualTerminalLevel /t REG_DWORD /d 1
  ) > Nul || Set "Win10="
 )
 If not defined Win10 (
  Echo(Virtual terminal sequences not supported on your system
  Exit /B 1
 )

 If "%~1" == "" (
  Mode 200,150
  Cls
 )

:# /@ Switch requires clean working driectory to execute in.
 RD "%TEMP%\%~n0_Run" 2> nul && Timeout 1 > nul
 MD "%TEMP%\%~n0_Run"

(Set \n=^^^

%= \n macro newline variable. Do not modify =%)

:# assign virtual terminal control character 0x27 'escape' variable \E
 For /F %%a in ( 'Echo prompt $E ^| cmd' )Do Set "\E=%%a"

::# usage: %$Cout% [/?] | [/Alt | /Main] [/H [-|+]] [/T Int] [/X Int | /L Int | /R Int]
::#                [/Y Int | /U Int | /D Int] [/K |/Del Int | /I Int] [/N] [/@ {Optional:ReturnVar}]
::#                [/C Int | /C Int,Int | /C Int;Int | /C random] [/S "String"] [/E {Optional:0|Int}]
::# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
::# Available Switches     : Description:
::# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
::# /?                     : This help screen
::#
::# /S String              : String to be output. Tested for strings of 500 characters.
::# /S String{Substituion} : The following characters must be substituted for output:
::# /S ^!Variable:/={FS}^! : {AS}:* {DQ}:" {FS}:/ {EQ}:=
::#
::# /C Integer             : Declare output color using VT sequence
::# /C Integer,Integer     : Chain   mulitple VT color sequences
::# /C Integer;Integer     : Combine multiple VT values into the one sequence
::# /C random              : Random RGB foreground color
::# /B R|G|B|C|M|Y         : Bias /C random color toward Red Green Blue
::#                        : Cyan Magenta or Yellow. /C random must be used.
::# /E                     : Preserves /C Color value until /E 0 is used. /C must be used.
::# /E 0                   : Restores color to Black BG White FG after string output.
::# /E Integer             : Change color after string output to supplied value.
::#
::# /A Integer;Integer     : Move cursor to Line;Column    [ absolute   ]
::# /Y Integer             : Move cursor to Line Integer   [ absolute Y ]
::# /X Integer             : Move cursor to Column Integer [ absolute X ]
::# /U Integer             : Move cursor Up by Integer
::# /D Integer             : Move cursor Down by Integer
::# /R Integer             : Move cursor Right by Integer
::# /L Integer             : Move cursor Left by Integer
::#
::# /H -                   : Hide the cursor  : Note - If Cursor state is changed during a code block
::#                          redirected to a file, it cannot be changed again except within a code block.
::# /H +                   : Show the cursor
::# /Alt                   : Switch to alternate   buffer [ main buffer is preserved ]
::# /Main                  : Return to main screen buffer [ alternate buffer is cleared ]
::# /K                     : Clears text to right of current cursor position
::# /Del Integer           : Deletes Integer columns right of the cursor, shifting existing text left
::# /I Integer             : Inserts whitespace into Integer columns right of Cursor, shifting text right
::# /N                     : Output a newline after other switches are executed.
::# /T Integer             : Subsecond Delay after output. 25000 = ~1 Second [ Depending on clockspeed ]
::#
::# /@                     : Stores cursor position after execution in variables: $Cout{Y} , $Cout{X}
::#                        : and $Cout{pos} ( VT format 'IntY;IntX' )
::# /@ String-ReturnVar    : Return values to ReturnVar{pos} ReturnVar{Y} ReturnVar{X}
::#                    *!* : This switch MUST NOT be used during codeblocks that redirect output
::#                        : Slow execution time. ~ 17x slower than typical $Cout expansion
::#                        : 12/100th's vs 0.7/100th's of a second [with a clockspeed of 2904]
::#
::#                                               Notes:
::# - $Cout Macro does not support Concatenation of Expansions.
::# - No error validation is performed on switch Integer subargs. Invalid Virtual Terminal sequences
::#   will be disregarded and output as a string.
::#
::# Virtual Terminal sequence resource:
::# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences
::# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Set $Cout_Switches="A" "Y" "X" "U" "D" "R" "L" "H" "Alt" "Main" "K" "Del" "I" "N" "T" "B" "C" "E" "S" "@"

 Set $Cout=For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (%\n%
  For %%G in ( %$Cout_Switches% )Do Set "$Cout_Switch[%%~G]="%\n%
  Set "$Cout_leading.args=!$Cout_args:*/=!"%\n%
  For /F "Delims=" %%G in ("!$Cout_leading.args!")Do Set "$Cout_leading.args=!$Cout_args:/%%G=!"%\n%
  Set ^"$Cout_args=!$Cout_args:"=!"%\n%
  Set "$Cout_i.arg=0"%\n%
  For %%G in (!$Cout_leading.args!)Do (%\n%
   Set /A "$Cout_i.arg+=1"%\n%
   Set "$Cout_arg[!$Cout_i.arg!]=%%~G"%\n%
  )%\n%
  If "!$Cout_Args:~-2,1!" == "/" (%\n%
   Set "$Cout_Switch[!$Cout_Args:~-1!]=true"%\n%
   If not "!$Cout_Args:/?=!." == "!$Cout_Args!." Set "$Cout_Switch[help]=true"%\n%
   Set "$Cout_Args=!$Cout_Args:~0,-2!"%\n%
  )%\n%
  For %%G in ( %$Cout_Switches% )Do If not "!$Cout_args:/%%~G =!" == "!$Cout_args!" (%\n%
   Set "$Cout_Switch[%%~G]=!$Cout_Args:*/%%~G =!"%\n%
   If not "!$Cout_Switch[%%~G]:*/=!" == "!$Cout_Switch[%%~G]!" (%\n%
    Set "$Cout_Trail[%%~G]=!$Cout_Switch[%%~G]:*/=!"%\n%
    For %%v in ("!$Cout_Trail[%%~G]!")Do (%\n%
     Set "$Cout_Switch[%%~G]=!$Cout_Switch[%%~G]: /%%~v=!"%\n%
     Set "$Cout_Switch[%%~G]=!$Cout_Switch[%%~G]:/%%~v=!"%\n%
    )%\n%
    Set "$Cout_Trail[%%~G]="%\n%
    If "!$Cout_Switch[%%~G]:~-1!" == " " Set "$Cout_Switch[%%~G]=!$Cout_Switch[%%~G]:~0,-1!"%\n%
    If "!$Cout_Switch[%%~G]!" == "" Set "$Cout_Switch[%%~G]=true"%\n%
   )%\n%
  )%\n%
  If /I "!$Cout_Switch[C]!" == "random" (%\n%
   If not "!$Cout_Switch[B]!" == ""   (Set "$Cout_MOD=100")Else Set "$Cout_MOD=200"%\n%
   Set /A "$Cout_RR=!random! %% !$Cout_MOD! + 50,$Cout_GG=!random! %% !$Cout_MOD! + 50,$Cout_BB=!random! %% !$Cout_MOD! + 50"%\n%
   If /I "!$Cout_Switch[B]!" == "R" Set "$Cout_RR=250"%\n%
   If /I "!$Cout_Switch[B]!" == "G" Set "$Cout_GG=250"%\n%
   If /I "!$Cout_Switch[B]!" == "B" Set "$Cout_BB=250"%\n%
   If /I "!$Cout_Switch[B]!" == "M" Set /A "$Cout_RR=!Random! %% 50 + 200,Cout_GG=0,$Cout_BB=!Random! %% 50 + 200"%\n%
   If /I "!$Cout_Switch[B]!" == "Y" Set /A "$Cout_RR=!Random! %% 90 + 100,Cout_GG=!Random! %% 90 + 90,$Cout_BB=0"%\n%
   If /I "!$Cout_Switch[B]!" == "C" Set /A "$Cout_RR=0,Cout_GG=!Random! %% 120 + 30,$Cout_BB=175"%\n%
   Set "$Cout_Switch[C]=38;2;!$Cout_RR!;!$Cout_GG!;!$Cout_BB!"%\n%
  )%\n%
  If "!$Cout_Switch[help]!" == "true" ((For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims=#" %%Y in ('findstr /BLIC:"::#" "%~f0"')Do @Echo(%%Z)^| @More)%\n%
  If not "!$Cout_Switch[C]!" == ""    (Set "$Cout_Color=%\E%[!$Cout_Switch[C]:,=m%\E%[!m")Else Set "$Cout_Color="%\n%
  If not "!$Cout_Switch[Y]!" == ""    (Set "$Cout_Ypos=%\E%[!$Cout_Switch[Y]!d")Else Set "$Cout_Ypos="%\n%
  If not "!$Cout_Switch[X]!" == ""    (Set "$Cout_Xpos=%\E%[!$Cout_Switch[X]!G")Else Set "$Cout_Xpos="%\n%
  For %%d in (U D L R)Do if not "!$Cout_Switch[%%d]!" == "" (Set /A "$Cout_Switch[%%d]=!$Cout_Switch[%%d]!")%\n%
  If not "!$Cout_Switch[U]!" == ""    (Set "$Cout_Yoffset=%\E%[!$Cout_Switch[U]!A")Else Set "$Cout_Yoffset="%\n%
  If not "!$Cout_Switch[D]!" == ""    Set "$Cout_Yoffset=%\E%[!$Cout_Switch[D]!B"%\n%
  If not "!$Cout_Switch[R]!" == ""    (Set "$Cout_Xoffset=%\E%[!$Cout_Switch[R]!C")Else Set "$Cout_Xoffset="%\n%
  If not "!$Cout_Switch[L]!" == ""    Set "$Cout_Xoffset=%\E%[!$Cout_Switch[L]!D"%\n%
  If "!$Cout_Switch[H]!" == "-"       Set "$Cout_Cursor=%\E%[?25l"%\n%
  If "!$Cout_Switch[H]!" == "+"       Set "$Cout_Cursor=%\E%[?25h"%\n%
  If "!$Cout_Switch[Main]!" == "true" (Set "$Cout_Buffer=%\E%[?1049l")Else Set "$Cout_Buffer="%\n%
  If "!$Cout_Switch[Alt]!" == "true"  Set "$Cout_Buffer=%\E%[?1049h"%\n%
  If not "!$Cout_Switch[A]!" == ""    (Set "$Cout_Absolutepos=%\E%[!$Cout_Switch[A]!H")Else Set "$Cout_Absolutepos="%\n%
  If not "!$Cout_Switch[K]!" == ""    (Set "$Cout_LineClear=%\E%[K")Else Set "$Cout_LineClear="%\n%
  If not "!$Cout_Switch[Del]!" == ""  (Set "$Cout_Delete=%\E%[!$Cout_Switch[Del]!P")Else Set "$Cout_Delete="%\n%
  If not "!$Cout_Switch[I]!" == ""    (Set "$Cout_Insert=%\E%[!$Cout_Switch[I]!@")Else Set "$Cout_Insert="%\n%
  If not "!$Cout_Switch[S]!" == ""    (%\n%
   Set "$Cout_String=!$Cout_Switch[S]:{FS}=/!"%\n%
   Set "$Cout_String=!$Cout_String:{EQ}==!"%\n%
   Set "$Cout_String=!$Cout_String:{AS}=*!"%\n%
   Set ^"$Cout_String=!$Cout_String:{DQ}="!"%\n%
  )Else (Set "$Cout_String=")%\n%
  If "!$Cout_Switch[E]!" == "true"    (Set "$Cout_EOLC=!$Cout_Color!")%\n%
  If not "!$Cout_Switch[E]!" == ""    (Set "$Cout_EOLC=%\E%[!$Cout_Switch[E]!m")%\n%
  If "!$Cout_EOLC!" == ""             (Set "$Cout_EOLC=%\E%[0m")%\n%
  ^< nul set /P "=!$Cout_Buffer!!$Cout_Cursor!!$Cout_Absolutepos!!$Cout_Ypos!!$Cout_YOffset!!$Cout_Xpos!!$Cout_XOffset!!$Cout_Delete!!$Cout_Insert!!$Cout_Color!!$Cout_LineClear!!$Cout_String!!$COUT_EOLC!"%\n%
  If "!$Cout_Switch[N]!" == "true"    Echo(%\n%
  If not "!$Cout_Switch[T]!" == ""    (For /L %%T in (1 1 !$Cout_Switch[T]!)Do (Call )%= Delay resetting Errorlevel to 0 =%)%\n%
  If "!$Cout_Switch[help]!" == "true" Pause%\n%
  If not "!$Cout_Switch[@]!" == "" (%\n%
   PUSHD "%TEMP%\%~n0_Run"%\n%
   Set "$Cout{pos}=" ^&Set "$Cout[Char]="%\n%
   For /L %%l in (2 1 12)Do (%\n%
    If not "!$Cout[Char]!" == "R" (%\n%
     ^<nul set /p "=%\E%[6n" %\n%
     FOR /L %%z in (1 1 %%l) DO pause ^< CON ^> NUL%\n%
     Set "$Cout[Char]=;"%\n%
     for /F "tokens=1 skip=1 delims=*" %%C in ('"REPLACE /W ? . < con"') DO (Set "$Cout[Char]=%%C")%\n%
     If "!$Cout{pos}!" == "" (Set "$Cout{pos}=!$Cout[Char]!")Else (set "$Cout{pos}=!$Cout{pos}!!$Cout[Char]:R=!")%\n%
   ))%\n%
   For /F "tokens=1,2 Delims=;" %%X in ("!$Cout{pos}!")Do Set "$Cout{Y}=%%X" ^& Set "$Cout{X}=%%Y" %\n%
   If not "!$Cout_Switch[@]!" == "true" (%\n%
    Set "{Pos}!$Cout_Switch[@]!=!$Cout{pos}!"%\n%
    Set /A "{Y}!$Cout_Switch[@]!=$Cout{Y},{X}!$Cout_Switch[@]!=$Cout{X}"%\n%
   )%\n%
   POPD "%TEMP%\%~n0_Run"%\n%
  )%\n%
 ) Else Set $Cout_args=

:# enable macro
Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:# facilitate testing of the macro using parameters from the command line; or Call %~n0.bat /? to see help.

 if not "%~1" == ""  (
  %$Cout% %*
  Exit /B !Errorlevel!
 )

:# usage example Ascii art ; Bird with animation

:# ensures Y;X axis at screen home
%$Cout% /A 1;1

(
%$Cout% /H - /C 1,33 /S "                ,      .-;" /N
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "             ,  |\    {FS} {FS}  __," /N
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "             |\ '.`-.|  |.'.-'" /N
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "              \`'-:  `; : {FS}" /N
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "               `-._'.  \'|" /N
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "              ,_.-` ` `  ~,_" /N
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "               '--,.    "
%$Cout% /C 31 /S ".-. "
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S ",{EQ}{DQ}{EQ}." /N
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "                 {FS}     "
%$Cout% /C 31 /S "{ "
%$Cout% /C 1,36 /S "} "
%$Cout% /C 31 /S ")"
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "`"
%$Cout% /C 33 /S ";-."
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "}" /N
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "                 |      "
%$Cout% /C 31 /S "'-' "
%$Cout% /C 33 /S "{FS}__ |" /N
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "                 {FS}          "
%$Cout% /C 33 /S "\_,\|" /N
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "                 |          (" /N
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "             "
%$Cout% /C 31 /S "__ "
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "{FS} '          \" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "     {FS}\_    "
%$Cout% /C 31 /S "{FS},'`"
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "|     '   "
%$Cout% /C 31 /S ".-~^~~-." /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "     |`.\_ "
%$Cout% /C 31 /S "|   "
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "{FS}  ' ,    "
%$Cout% /C 31 /S "{FS}        \" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "   _{FS}  `, \"
%$Cout% /C 31 /S "|  "
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "; ,     . "
%$Cout% /C 31 /S "|  ,  '  . |" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "   \   `,  "
%$Cout% /C 31 /S "|  "
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "|  ,  ,   "
%$Cout% /C 31 /S "|  :  ;  : |" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "   _\  `,  "
%$Cout% /C 31 /S "\  "
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "|.     ,  "
%$Cout% /C 31 /S "|  |  |  | |" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "   \`  `.   "
%$Cout% /C 31 /S "\ "
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "|   '     "
%$Cout% /C 1,32 /S "|"
%$Cout% /C 31 /S "\_|-'|_,'\|" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "   _\   `,   "
%$Cout% /C 1,32 /S "`"
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "\  '  . ' "
%$Cout% /C 1,32 /S "| |  | |  |           "
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "__" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "   \     `,   "
%$Cout% /C 33 /S "| ,  '    "
%$Cout% /C 1,32 /S "|_{FS}'-|_\_{FS}     "
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "__ ,-;` {FS}" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "    \    `,    "
%$Cout% /C 33 /S "\ .  , ' .| | | | |   "
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "_{FS}' ` _-`|" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "     `\    `,   "
%$Cout% /C 33 /S "\     ,  | | | | |"
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "_{FS}'   .{EQ}{DQ}  {FS}" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "     \`     `,   "
%$Cout% /C 33 /S "`\      \{FS}|,| ;"
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "{FS}'   .{EQ}{DQ}    |" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "      \      `,    "
%$Cout% /C 33 /S "`\' ,  | ; "
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "{FS}'    {EQ}{DQ}    _{FS}" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "       `\     `,  "
%$Cout% /C random /B M /S ".{EQ}{DQ}-. "
%$Cout% /C 1,33 /S "': "
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "{FS}'     {EQ}{DQ}    .{FS}" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "    jgs _`\    ;"
%$Cout% /C random /B M /S "_{  '   ; "
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "{FS}'    {EQ}{DQ}      {FS}" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "       _\`-{FS}__"
%$Cout% /C random /B M /S ".~  `."
%$Cout% /C 1,35,7,48;2;130;100;0 /S "8"
%$Cout% /C random /B M /S ".'.^`~-. "
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "{EQ}{DQ}     _,{FS}" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "    __\      "
%$Cout% /C random /B M /S "{   '-."
%$Cout% /C 1,35,7,48;2;150;130;0 /S "|"
%$Cout% /C random /B M /S ".'.--~'`}"
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "     _{FS}" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "    \    .{EQ}{DQ}` "
%$Cout% /C random /B M /S "}.-~^'"
%$Cout% /C 1,35,7,48;2;170;150;0 /S "@"
%$Cout% /C random /B M /S "'-. '-..'  "
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "__{FS}" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "   _{FS}  .{DQ}    "
%$Cout% /C random /B M /S "{  -'.~('-._,.'"
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "\_,{FS}" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "  {FS}  .{DQ}    _{FS}'"
%$Cout% /C random /B M /S "`--; ;  `.  ;" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "   .{EQ}{DQ}   _{FS}'      "
%$Cout% /C random /B M /S "`-..__,-'" /N
%$Cout% /C random /B G /S "     __{FS}'" /N
) > "%~dp0parrot.brd"
TYPE "%~dp0parrot.brd"
DEL "%~dp0parrot.brd"

:# Just a bit of animation
For /L %%i in (0 1 25)Do (
 %$Cout% /Y 25 /X 19 /C random /B M /S ".{EQ}{DQ}-. "
 %$Cout% /D 1 /X 17 /C random /B M /S "_{  '   ; "
 %$Cout% /D 1 /X 15 /C random /B M /S ".~  `."
 %$Cout% /R 1 /C random /B M /S ".'.^`~-. "
 %$Cout% /D 1 /X 14 /C random /B M /S "{   '-."
 %$Cout% /R 1 /C random /B M /S ".'.--~'`}"
 %$Cout% /D 1 /X 15 /C random /B M /S "}.-~^'"
 %$Cout% /R 1 /C random /B M /S "'-. '-..'  "
 %$Cout% /D 1 /X 14 /C random /B M /S "{  -'.~('-._,.'"
 %$Cout% /D 1 /X 15 /C random /B M /S "`--; ;  `.  ;"
 %$Cout% /D 1 /X 19 /C random /B M /S "`-..__,-'"
 %$Cout% /T 15 /Y 8 /X 26 /C random /B C /S }
 %$Cout% /D 2 /R 5 /I 2
 %$Cout% /U 1 /R 1 /C 33 /S \
 %$Cout% /Y 25 /X 19 /C random /B M /S ".{EQ}{DQ}-. "
 %$Cout% /D 1 /X 17 /C random /B M /S "_{  '   ; "
 %$Cout% /D 1 /X 15 /C random /B M /S ".~  `."
 %$Cout% /R 1 /C random /B M /S ".'.^`~-. "
 %$Cout% /D 1 /X 14 /C random /B M /S "{   '-."
 %$Cout% /R 1 /C random /B M /S ".'.--~'`}"
 %$Cout% /D 1 /X 15 /C random /B M /S "}.-~^'"
 %$Cout% /R 1 /C random /B M /S "'-. '-..'  "
 %$Cout% /D 1 /X 14 /C random /B M /S "{  -'.~('-._,.'"
 %$Cout% /D 1 /X 15 /C random /B M /S "`--; ;  `.  ;"
 %$Cout% /D 1 /X 19 /C random /B M /S "`-..__,-'"
 %$Cout% /T 15 /Y 8 /X 26 /C random /B B /S {EQ}
 %$Cout% /D 2 /R 5 /Del 2
 %$Cout% /U 1 /R 1 /C 33 /S "|"
 If %%i EQU 25 %$Cout% /H + /Y 34 /X 1 /C 33 /S example 2 done /N
)

Goto :Eof
```

[image: Parrot]

Answer (score 0):

I liked the function approach posted by @jeb but there are a few small issues with his (second) solution:

- the X file is not deleted
- any X file is overwritten if present in the folder
- the '^' character is not actually working
- no newline after the colored "echo"
- no pause after test bat file

That is why I feel to share my solution to these issues, insted of requesting an invasive edit.

```batch
@echo off

call :colorEcho 1a "a"
call :colorEcho 1b "b"
call :colorEcho 1c "^!<>:&| %%%%"*?"
echo.
pause
exit /b

:colorEcho
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
      set "DEL=%%a"
    )
    set "param=^%~2" !
    set "param=!param:"=\"!"
    rem Prepare a file "æ" with only one dot
    <nul > æ set /p ".=."
    findstr /p /A:%1 "." "!param!\..\æ" nul
    <nul set /p ".=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
    rem Delete "æ" file
    del æ
    echo.
    endlocal
    exit /b
```

Comments to this script in comparison to @jeb one:

- the X file is now named "æ", which is more unlikely to exist
- this "æ" file is removed after the function is called
- the '^' character is now permitted
- a newline is added after every function call *(you can remove it if you want)*
- a final pause gives you the opportunity to better test this code.