# Creating colors in the middle of a line in batch?

Tags: batch-file, colors

Is there a way to make it so I can display text like so?:

Hello, how are you?

And have each word be a different color?

In batch code.
I know about the Color command, though :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to have multiple colors in a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 2):

Unlike what fvu said, there is a rather easy way to do this.

First, copy this into your text editor and save it as `ncol.bat`. Make sure you save it in the same place as the other file.

```
@echo off
setlocal
if "%~1"=="/?" (
echo.
echo    ncol ["Text"] [Colour]
echo.
echo "Text" - The text you want displayed in another colour.
echo          Remember that spaces cannot be added if you don't put the text in
echo          quotation marks (""^).
echo.
echo Colour - The hexadecimal colour code that you want the text to be changed into.
echo          For more information of colour codes, see "color /?"
echo.
exit /b
)
for /f "delims=#" %%i in ('"prompt #$H# &for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "bs=%%i"
<nul >"%~1.@" set /p "=.%bs%%bs%%bs%%bs%"
findstr /p /a:%2 . "*.@"
endlocal
del "*.@"
@echo on
@exit /b
```

Here's an example of how to use it...

```
ncol "Hello, " 01 && ncol "how " 02 && ncol "are " 03 && ncol "you" 04
```

This would display `Hello,` in red on black, `how` in green on black, `are` in cyan on black and `you` in red on black.

Unfortunately, my simple version can't process special characters (like question marks), but there are some out there that can (there's both one on this site and www.dostips.com).

So, goodluck.

Comment: @user Did it help you? Did it answer your question? If it did you should probably accept my answer or vote up for people with the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, if you use [**cmdcolor**](https://github.com/jeremejevs/cmdcolor):

```
echo \033[91mHello, \033[92mhow \033[93mare \033[94myou?
```

`Hello,` will be red, `how` - green, `are` - yellow, and `you?` - blue.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't because cmd doesn't understand eg the ANSI escape sequences that would be needed to modify the text color.  Now, depending on how adventurous you are, [this neat trick](http://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=130), extra utilities like [ansicon](http://jasonkarns.com/blog/ansi-color-in-windows-shells/) or using bash might all be possible workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

With using Visual Studio Community 2015 people (and I) have made programs to expand BATCH limitations. Basically, people (and I) make an external "Command" if you will. [Batbox](http://dos9.org/doc/en/html/batbox.html) gets the job done the best. Put the Application in the Current Directory of the BATCH File and try doing something like this

```
batbox /g 20 20 /c 0x0f /d "Hello" /c 0x0a /d " World" /c 0x09 /d "!"
```

It should come with colorful text saying "Hello World!". Batbox uses tags
 [here are all tags](http://dos9.org/doc/en/html/batbox.html). Put i'll give you a few

```
/g = Cursor Position (Ex: batbox /g 20 20)
/c = Color (Ex: batbox /c 0x0f) Make sure 0x is before color
/d = Prints text. (Ex: batbox /d "Hello World")
```

Also you can get Mouse clicks and Keystroke in this!

```
batbox /k
```

keystroke will return in %errorlevel% and in keyboard format (numbers)

```
batbox /m
batbox /y
```

will get mouse clicks. Since it returns three exit codes we need to a for statement.

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2,3" %%A in ('batbox /m') do set/a "x=%%A", "y=%%B", "M=%%C"
```

X and Y should but self exploratory, but what is M you ask? M is the variable for which was clicked. Left click and right click. Left click=1 Right click=2. If a key way pressed it will return a number in a format idk. In a wrap up [batbox](http://dos9.org/doc/en/html/batbox.html) can do a lot of things!