# MS DOS Batch file heading color

Tags: colors, batch-file, cmd, dos

I create a utility to automate some tasks in windows using .bat file. I have only MS DOS commands there. Once, I execute the .bat file it displays the command prompt with default colors. Black background and white fore ground.

I tried to change it with color command "COLOR 02" (i.e, green foreground), but it changes the entire console color.

Is there any command in command prompt that changes only one line color, but keeps the remaining lines in black and white only.

I want to highlight only the title of the utility in green color.

Comment: from the responses I got till now, I believe there is no single line sweet solution for this :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to have multiple colors in a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: well, i did more search for this, and noticed a topic called **Ansi Sequence**. Will this be useful for me, anyway? [http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ansi.php#AnsiColor](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ansi.php#AnsiColor)

Comment: No, ANSI escape sequences only work on old DOS machines. I'm assuming you are using the command line console on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

you should look at other questions in the forum :)

but here you go :
[How to have multiple colors in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: ya.. i too noticed this post before posting, but that one is complicate for me, and not able to find the solution for my question. Can you give me a simple single line solution, if it is available?

Comment: A single line solution is to use ColorShow.exe auxiliary program this way: `ColorShow /02 "Title of the Utility"`. Look for program # 12 at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3428&p=17750#p17750). The only drawback is that you must create ColorShow.exe file, but this is relatively simple and must be done just one time.