# typing text in bat script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm creating a script in a batch file. I want it to look someone is typing text when they open it.

Is there a easy way to do this? I didn't find anything in the last hour. Maybe I didn't search good

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `SET` command. the `/P` parameter is what you're looking for, I think.

Comment: waht do you mean - can you show an example?

Comment: Thanks for th reply.

I mean something like the matrix. Just a typing effect. That you look at you screen nobody is pressing a button on your keyboard and you see new characters coming on your cmd/dos/bat screen.

Comment: I hope this explains it a little more.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-batch-file#comments-link-5344911

The second code thing. When you past that in a batch file it looks like someone is typing on your screen some randon stuff.

Comment: Is there a easy way to do this ?

Comment: `echo Text` with echo the word Text to the screen. What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: But that isn't what i'm looking for. I will search on ddg.gg to explain it better here.

Comment: Something like this : http://www.cgkmussel.nl/lichtkrant2.html

But than in a .bat script.

Comment: Ahh. Here is a example of that: http://www.computerforum.com/134296-cmd-typing-effect.html

Comment: Thanks ! I will look. 
update: Ok, thats a way to do it. But why the ping ?

Comment: @user The ping acts as a delay in the script, giving it that "typing effect".

Comment: I found this and i will use it. Thanks

<pre>
@Echo off
title Typewriter effect 
echo H
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 2.5 > NUL
cls
echo He
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 2.5 > NUL
cls
echo Hel
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 2.5 > NUL
cls
echo Hell
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 2.5 > NUL
cls
echo Hello?
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 2.5 > NUL
cls
echo Hello? A
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 2.5 > NUL
cls
echo Hello? An
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 2.5 > NUL
cls
echo Hello? Any
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 2.5 > NUL
cls
echo Hello? Anyo
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 2.5 > NUL
cls
echo Hello? Anyon
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 2.5 > NUL
cls
echo Hello? Anyone
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 2.5 > NUL
cls
echo Hello? Anyone?
pause >nul
</pre>

Comment: [How to Create the Matrix Rain in Command Prompt](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-the-Matrix-Rain-in-Command-Prompt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
for %%i in (h e l l o) do (
   set /p a=%%i<nul
   ping 0.0.0.0 -n 2.5>nul 2>&1
)
```

try this

**EDIT**

this is what i use now

```
@ECHO OFF
call :talk %*
exit /b

:talk
if "%~1" EQU "" exit /b
set _=%~1
for /f "tokens=2 delims=# " %%i in ('prompt #$E#$H# ^& cmd /k ^<nul') do set BS=%%i
set speed=
if "%~2" EQU "" set speed=10000
if "%~2" EQU "/s" set speed=15000
if "%~2" EQU "/f" set speed=4000
if not defined speed (
      echo useage: %~n0 "text" ^(/f^|/s^)
      exit /b
)
:top
set /p=.%BS%%_:~0,1%<nul
for /l %%i in (1,1,%speed%) do call
set _=%_:~1%
if defined _ goto top
exit /b
```

Comment: I will try it. Thansk for the reply !

Comment: Thanks so much ! This is much better than reply a rule 1000 times. Thanks !!