# How do I use multiple colors on one screen using batch

Tags: batch-file

I tried this:

```
@echo off
color 0a
echo This is text
color 0b
echo This is different color text
```

Obviously it didn't work and it makes complete sense (to me) that it should work.

Anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: I know points have been awarded..  But this is cool and needs no install (stand-alone) and there is an install version too - http://www.softwareok.com/?Freeware/ColorConsole

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to have multiple colors in a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 2):

here's a color function by carlos:
http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4453