# I need some help in a Batch script please

Tags: batch-file

I made a game menu and the "2" works gret but when i click "5" it adds +1 to "menumark"
BTW I have Windows 7.
Some more questions:
1) Can you put a color to a specific letter?
2) Why doesnt: if errorlevel 3 set /a menumark=%menumark%-1 work?
Code:

```
...
...
...
set menumark=1
set checkmark=1
set mark1=/
set mark2=.
set mark3=.
...
...
...
:MENU
cls
echo ----------
echo %mark1% (1) Play.
echo %mark2% (2) Settings.
echo %mark3% (3) Scores.
echo ----------
choice /c 25 /n
if errorlevel 1 set /a menumark=%menumark%+1
if errorlevel 2 set checkmark=2
if %menumark%==4 set menumark=1
if %menumark%==0 set menumark=1
if %menumark%==1 set mark1=/&set mark2=.&set mark3=.
if %menumark%==2 set mark2=/&set mark1=.&set mark3=.
if %menumark%==3 set mark3=/&set mark2=.&set mark1=.
if %checkmark%==2 if %menumark%==1 goto TOP
if %checkmark%==2 if %menumark%==2 goto SETTINGS
if %checkmark%==2 if %menumark%==3 goto HIGHSCORE
goto MENU
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the control of `errorlevel`. The code `if errorlevel n command` will execute the indicated command for any `errorlevel` value greater or equal to `n`. For this reason, to use this kind of testing it is necessary to test from greater to lower values of `errorlevel` and properly code to avoid problems

```
if errorlevel 3 echo 3
if errorlevel 2 echo 2
if errorlevel 1 echo 1
```

if your errorlevel is 3, the previous code will echo the three values, as all the conditions are evaluated to true.

```
if errorlevel 3 (
    echo 3
) else if errorlevel 2 (
    echo 2 
) else if errorlevel 1 (
    echo 1
) else echo no error level


if %errorlevel%==3 echo 3
if %errorlevel%==2 echo 2
if %errorlevel%==1 echo 1
```

Both versions will avoid the "problem" (or you can use `goto`s to avoid falling through the options)

For the color management, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4339649/2861476) you can find all the required information.