# Open CMD window on right side

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm launching my python script with a `.bat` file. The python script open in the left side > `... driver.set_window_position(1, 0)...`

I already know how to configure the size of the batch.

It's possible to specify the position where the window of the `cmd` will open up?

**batch code:**

```
MODE CON: COLS=80 LINES=30
python web.py
```

Comment: my python code just is running on the desired position. I only want to change the batch windows position.

Comment: edit your question to clariy that point In your question,you state `windows` plural, and you included code provides no context. VBS can be used to reposition the cmd window. [see my answer here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61046030/12343998)

Comment: No, batch files are not capable of interacting with GUI windows (with the exception of `mode` and `start` commands, both of which cannot position windows)…

Comment: There are 100000 programs that can do this. Here is one https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2021/03/movewindowexe-moves-window.html?m=1