# Using multiple colors in matrix batch file

Tags: batch-file, random, matrix, colors, command-prompt

I've been messing around with batch files a bit, and have this code running. I did not write it, I found it, and it just runs random blue numbers in command prompt until you exit. My question is this, I want to make one where every character is a random color. so essentially, it'll look like a rainbow vomited skittles on my screen. But i digress. That is my challenge, and so far i have failed at solving it. Any ideas would be great!

```
@echo off
color 01
cls
:a
set /a a=%random%
if %a% geq 16384 set /a aa=1
if %a% lss 16384 set /a aa=0
set /a b=%random%
if %b% geq 16384 set /a bb=1
if %b% lss 16384 set /a bb=0
set /a c=%random%
if %c% geq 16384 set /a cc=1
if %c% lss 16384 set /a cc=0
set /a d=%random%
if %d% geq 16384 set /a dd=1
if %d% lss 16384 set /a dd=0
set /a e=%random%
if %e% geq 16384 set /a ee=1
if %e% lss 16384 set /a ee=0
set /a f=%random%
if %f% geq 16384 set /a ff=1
if %f% lss 16384 set /a ff=0
set /a g=%random%
if %g% geq 16384 set /a gg=1
if %g% lss 16384 set /a gg=0
set /a h=%random%
if %h% geq 16384 set /a hh=1
if %h% lss 16384 set /a hh=0
set /a i=%random%
if %i% geq 16384 set /a ii=1
if %i% lss 16384 set /a ii=0
set /a j=%random%
if %j% geq 16384 set /a jj=1
if %j% lss 16384 set /a jj=0
set /a k=%random%
if %k% geq 16384 set /a kk=1
if %k% lss 16384 set /a kk=0
set /a l=%random%
if %l% geq 16384 set /a ll=1
if %l% lss 16384 set /a ll=0
set /a m=%random%
if %m% geq 16384 set /a mm=1
if %m% lss 16384 set /a mm=0
set /a n=%random%
if %n% geq 16384 set /a nn=1
if %n% lss 16384 set /a nn=0
set /a o=%random%
if %o% geq 16384 set /a oo=1
if %o% lss 16384 set /a oo=0
set /a p=%random%
if %p% geq 16384 set /a pp=1
if %p% lss 16384 set /a pp=0
set /a q=%random%
if %q% geq 16384 set /a qq=1
if %q% lss 16384 set /a qq=0
set /a r=%random%
if %r% geq 16384 set /a rr=1
if %r% lss 16384 set /a rr=0
set /a s=%random%
if %s% geq 16384 set /a ss=1
if %s% lss 16384 set /a ss=0
set /a t=%random%
if %t% geq 16384 set /a tt=1
if %t% lss 16384 set /a tt=0
set /a u=%random%
if %u% geq 16384 set /a uu=1
if %u% lss 16384 set /a uu=0
set /a v=%random%
if %v% geq 16384 set /a vv=1
if %v% lss 16384 set /a vv=0
set /a w=%random%
if %w% geq 16384 set /a ww=1
if %w% lss 16384 set /a ww=0
set /a x=%random%
if %x% geq 16384 set /a xx=1
if %x% lss 16384 set /a xx=0
set /a y=%random%
if %y% geq 16384 set /a yy=1
if %y% lss 16384 set /a yy=0
set /a z=%random%
if %z% geq 16384 set /a zz=1
if %z% lss 16384 set /a zz=0
echo %aa% %bb% %cc% %dd% %ee% %ff% %gg% %hh% %ii% %jj% %kk% %ll% %mm% %nn% %oo% %pp% %qq% %rr% %ss% %tt% %uu% %vv% %ww% %xx% %yy% %zz%
goto a
```

Comment: so you want to do the same but every character to have different color?

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4339649/1683264) for several possible solutions for printing characters in various colors.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you got it yet but I had the same thought 
and Decided to look it up I could not find anything but how to use colors and a random number generator so here's what I got

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
set "DEL=%%a"
)
:a-0a0
set eddie=%time:~-2% 
set first=%eddie:~0,1% 
if %first%==0 set eddie=%eddie:~1,1%
set /a eddie=(%eddie%%%9)
call :ColorText 0%eddie% " %random%"
goto a-0a0
pause >null

:ColorText
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
```