# Rainbow Matrix CMD

Tags: batch-file, matrix, cmd

I want to run the Matrix.bat CMD with a different color on each line to make a rainbow effect.
Here is the Matrix.bat

```
@echo off 
color ##
:start 
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random% 
goto :start
```

I have tried experimenting myself but have not succeeded with my low level experience. Here is where I got with my experimentation.

```
@echo off 
:start
color 01 
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
color 02
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
color 04
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
color 05 
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
color 06
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
goto :start
```

When I tried this it changed the whole command prompts color instead of the individual lines of %random%. Hopefully someone more experienced can give me some pointers on how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have multiple colors in a Windows batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: This will get you a little closer to what you want to do but it only shows random numbers in different colors.  Does not look very Matrix like. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32792029/1417694

Comment: Thank you for the references. I will look into them later and see what I can do.

Answer (score 2):

With [Ansi escape codes](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mlocati/fdabcaeb8071d5c75a2d51712db24011/raw/b710612d6320df7e146508094e84b92b34c77d48/win10colors.cmd), rapid, smooth and EASY rainbow (or other) matrix's can be achieved.

[This linked code](https://pastebin.com/8f26H5mK) can alternate between the following outputs, with a very simple process to incorperate new output styles.
I've remarked throughout the code what's being done and how / why.

the default: Smooth transitioning color changes (Waterfall like)

[image: enter image description here][1]

Rapid Chaotic color from one character to the next. flow is still smooth.

[image: Rainbow Chaos]

The matrix animation occurs in this code block:

```
:loop
For /L %%A in (1,1,125) do (
%= lower for loop end value equals faster transition, higher equals slower. Result of nCI color variable not being expanded with new value during for loop =%
    Set /A Xpos=!random! %%!Console_Width! + 1,Ypos=!random! %%!Console_Hieght! + 1,Char=!random! %%80 + 1,nCI=!random! %%!CI#! + 1
    %@P% !Ypos!;!Xpos! C!Char! !C#[%nCI%]!
)
Goto :loop
```

The loop updates variables for cursor X and Y positions, the Character to be printed and the color to print it in using Random number Generation to access arrays for each non X Y value.
Once those values are updated, they are expanded as arguments to the following Macro to action the ANSI codes changing position and color with the Echo command.

```
    Set @P=for /L %%n in (1 1 2) do if %%n==2 (%\n%
        For /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=, " %%G in ("!argv!") do (%\n%
            Echo(![!%%G!]!!%%I!!%%H!!Off!^&^&Endlocal%\n%
        ) %\n%
    ) ELSE setlocal enableDelayedExpansion ^& set argv=,
```

Inclusion of the `^&^&Endlocal` after performing the echo command is integral to preventing the setlocal recursion threshold being exceeded. Escaping the Ampersands prevent the Endlocal from destroying the macro during definition.

The choice to use a macro to conduct the processing of arguments makes this script both smooth and [***Insanely Fast***.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4U2AKemEvBE)

A variant modified to use character mapping through substring modification and random string lengths. The below variant also uses a method of assigning the ASCII 27 escape code to a variable, without requiring the actual ASCII 27 character.

```
@Echo Off & CD "%~dp0"

::: / Variable used in calling this script from the Self created resizing Batch.    
    Set "AlignFile=%~dpnx0"
::: \

::: / Creates variable /AE = Ascii-27 escape code.
::: - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1733
::: - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34923514/12343998
:::
::: - /AE can be used  with and without DelayedExpansion.
    Setlocal
    For /F "tokens=2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
        Endlocal
        Set "/AE=%%a"
    )
::: \

::: / Set environment state for Macro Definitions
    Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

    (Set LF=^


    %= Above Empty lines Required =%)

    Set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^"


::: / Color Macro Variables
::: - Macro used to print the "%%H"th character (Passed with randomly set Char variable as the 2nd Arg) from the defined Character Set
::: - At Y;X Position (Arg 1, %%G) in Color %%H
    Set @PrintMapped=for /L %%n in (1 1 2) do if %%n==2 (%\n%
        For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=, " %%G in ("!argv!") do (%\n%
            Echo(%/AE%[%%GH!%%I!!CharacterSet:~%%H,%%J!!Off!^&^&Endlocal%\n%
        ) %\n%
    ) ELSE setlocal enableDelayedExpansion ^& set argv=, 
::: -
::: - Macro used to print content of Variable passed with 2nd Arg (%%H)
::: - At Y;X Position (%%G) in Color %%H
    Set @Menu=for /L %%n in (1 1 2) do if %%n==2 (%\n%
        For /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=, " %%G in ("!argv!") do (%\n%
            Echo(%/AE%[%%GH!%%I!!%%H!!Off!^&^&Endlocal%\n%
        ) %\n%
    ) ELSE setlocal enableDelayedExpansion ^& set argv=, 
::: \ End Macro Definitions

::: / Assigns ANSI color code values to each color, then builds an Array containing those color values to be accessed using random number.
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set /A Red=31,Green=32,Yellow=33,Blue=34,Purple=35,Cyan=36,White=37,Grey=90,Pink=91,Beige=93,Aqua=94,Magenta=95,Teal=96,Off=0,CI#=0
    For %%A in (Red,Yellow,Pink,Beige,Grey,Purple,Green,Cyan,White,Aqua,Magenta,Blue,Teal,Off) do (
        Set "%%A=%/AE%[!%%A!m"
        Set /A "CI#+=1"
        Set "C#[!CI#!]=%%A"
    )
::: \

::: / Define character Set to be used. Accessed using Random number and Substring Modification to extract the character at that mapped position
    Set "CharacterSet=1qA{Z2W<sX[3EDC@4R}FV^5TG&BYHn7]UJM8-IK9OL0Ppo_iu>ytre$wQ\aSdf/gh~jkl+mN|bvc#xz"
::: \

::: / Identifies when the program has been called by the resizung batch it creates and goes to label passed by call
    If Not "%~3"=="" (
        Set "Console_Hieght=%~1"
        Set "Console_Width=%~2"
        Set "AlignFile=%~4"
        Goto :%~3
    ) Else (Goto :main)
::: \


::: / Subroutine to process output of wmic command into usable variables  for screen dimensions (resolution)

    :ChangeConsole <Lines> <Columns> <Label to Resume From> <If a 4th parameter is Defined, Aligns screen at top left>
::: - Get screen Dimensions
    For /f "delims=" %%# in  ('"wmic path Win32_VideoController  get CurrentHorizontalResolution,CurrentVerticalResolution /format:value"') do (
        Set "%%#">nul
    )
::: -  Calculation of X axis relative to screen resolution and console size

    Set /A CentreX= ( ( CurrentHorizontalResolution / 2 ) - ( %~2 * 4 ) ) + 8

::: - Sub Optimal calculation of Y axis relative to screen resolution and console size
    For /L %%A in (10,10,%1) DO Set /A VertMod+=1
    Set /A CentreY= ( CurrentVerticalResolution / 4 ) - ( %~1 * Vertmod )
    For /L %%B in (1,1,%VertMod%) do Set /A CentreY+= ( VertMod * 2 )

::: - Optional 4th parameter can be used to align console at top left of screen instead of screen centre
    If Not "%~4"=="" (Set /A CentreY=0,CentreX=-8)

    Set "Console_Width=%~2"

::: - Creates a batch file to reopen the main script using Call with parameters to define properties for console change and the label to resume from.
        (
        Echo.@Mode Con: lines=%~1 cols=%~2
        Echo.@Title Rainbow Matrix by T3RRY
        Echo.@Call "%AlignFile%" "%~1" "%~2" "%~3" "%AlignFile%" 
        )>"%temp%\ChangeConsole.bat"

::: - .Vbs script creation and launch to reopen batch with new console settings, with aid of above batch script
        (
        Echo.Set objWMIService = GetObject^("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2"^)
        Echo.Set objConfig = objWMIService.Get^("Win32_ProcessStartup"^)
        Echo.objConfig.SpawnInstance_
        Echo.objConfig.X = %CentreX%
        Echo.objConfig.Y = %CentreY%
        Echo.Set objNewProcess = objWMIService.Get^("Win32_Process"^)
        Echo.intReturn = objNewProcess.Create^("%temp%\ChangeConsole.bat", Null, objConfig, intProcessID^)
        )>"%temp%\Consolepos.vbs"

::: - Starts the companion batch script to Change Console properties, ends the parent.
    Start "" "%temp%\Consolepos.vbs" & Exit

:main

    Call :ChangeConsole 45 170 Matrix top

::: / Display Elements  
:Matrix
Setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

::: - Numbers higher than actual console hieght cause the the console to scroll. the higher the number, the smoother the scroll
::: - and the less dense the characters on screen will be.
    Set /A Console_Hieght=(Console_Hieght * 5) / 4
::: - Menu Selection
    Set "Opt1=(W)aterfall %cyan%Matrix"
    Set "Opt2=(C)haos     %red%M%yellow%a%green%t%blue%r%purple%i%magenta%x"
    Set "Opt3=%red%(%pink%R%magenta%)%purple%a%blue%i%aqua%n%cyan%b%green%o%yellow%w %red%painting"
    Set "Opt4=(F)laming %yellow%Matrix"
    %@Menu% 1;1 Opt1 blue
    %@Menu% 2;1 Opt2 magenta
    %@Menu% 3;1 Opt3 aqua
    %@Menu% 4;1 Opt4 red
    Choice /N /C WCRF /M ""
    CLS & Goto :loop%Errorlevel%

:loop1
TITLE Flow Matrix By T3RRY
:1loop
    For /L %%A in (1,1,125) do (
%= lower for loop end value equals faster transition, higher equals slower. Result of nCI color variable not being expanded with new value during for loop =%
        Set /A Xpos=!random! %%!Console_Width! + 1,Ypos=!random! %%!Console_Hieght! + 1,Char=!random! %%79 + 1,nCI=!random! %%!CI#! + 1,CharCount=!random! %%3 + 1
        %@PrintMapped% !Ypos!;!Xpos! !Char! !C#[%nCI%]! !CharCount!
    )
Goto :1loop

:loop2
TITLE Chaos Matrix By T3RRY
:2loop
    For /L %%A in (1,1,5000) do ( 
        Set /A Xpos=!random! %%!Console_Width! + 1,Ypos=!random! %%!Console_Hieght! + 1,Char=!random! %%79 + 1,nCI=!random! %%!CI#! + 1,CharCount=!random! %%3 + 1
        For %%B in (!nCI!) do %@PrintMapped% !Ypos!;!Xpos! !Char! !C#[%%B]! !CharCount!
    )
Goto :2loop

:loop3
TITLE Rainbow painter By T3RRY
    Set /A Console_Hieght=((Console_Hieght / 5) * 4) - 4
:3loop
    Set /A Xpos=!random! %%!Console_Width! + 1,Ypos=!random! %%!Console_Hieght! + 1,Char=!random! %%79 + 1,nCI=!random! %%!CI#! + 1,CharCount=!random! %%3 + 1
    For %%B in (!nCI!) do %@PrintMapped% !Ypos!;!Xpos! !Char! !C#[%%B]! !CharCount!
Goto :3loop

:loop4
TITLE Flaming Matrix By T3RRY
:4loop
    For /L %%A in (1,1,200000) do ( 
        Set /A Xpos=!random! %%!Console_Width! + 1,Ypos=!random! %%!Console_Hieght! + 1,Char=!random! %%79 + 1,nCI=!random! %%!CI#! + 1,CharCount=!random! %%5 + 1
        For %%B in (!nCI!) do %@PrintMapped% !Ypos!;!Xpos! !Char! !C#[2]! !CharCount!
        Set /A Xpos-=1,Ypos+=1,Char=!random! %%79 + 1,nCI=!random! %%!CI#! + 1,CharCount=!random! %%6 + 1
        For %%B in (!nCI!) do %@PrintMapped% !Ypos!;!Xpos! !Char! !C#[1]! !CharCount!
        Set /A Xpos=!random! %%!Console_Width! + 1,Ypos=!random! %%!Console_Hieght! + 1,Char=!random! %%79 + 1,nCI=!random! %%!CI#! + 1,CharCount=!random! %%5 + 1
        For %%B in (!nCI!) do %@PrintMapped% !Ypos!;!Xpos! !Char! !C#[2]! !CharCount!
        Set /A Xpos-=1,Ypos+=1,Char=!random! %%79 + 1,nCI=!random! %%!CI#! + 1,CharCount=!random! %%6 + 1
        For %%B in (!nCI!) do %@PrintMapped% !Ypos!;!Xpos! !Char! !C#[1]! !CharCount!
        Set /A Xpos=!random! %%!Console_Width! + 1,Ypos=!random! %%!Console_Hieght! + 1,Char=!random! %%79 + 1,nCI=!random! %%!CI#! + 1,CharCount=!random! %%5 + 1
        For %%B in (!nCI!) do %@PrintMapped% !Ypos!;!Xpos! !Char! !C#[2]! !CharCount!
        Set /A Xpos+=1,Ypos+=1,Char=!random! %%79 + 1,nCI=!random! %%!CI#! + 1,CharCount=!random! %%6 + 1
        For %%B in (!nCI!) do %@PrintMapped% !Ypos!;!Xpos! !Char! !C#[1]! !CharCount!
        Set /A Xpos=!random! %%!Console_Width! + 1,Ypos=!random! %%!Console_Hieght! + 1,Char=!random! %%79 + 1,nCI=!random! %%!CI#! + 1,CharCount=!random! %%5 + 1
        For %%B in (!nCI!) do %@PrintMapped% !Ypos!;!Xpos! !Char! !C#[2]! !CharCount!
        Set /A Xpos+=1,Ypos-=1,Char=!random! %%79 + 1,nCI=!random! %%!CI#! + 1,CharCount=!random! %%6 + 1
        For %%B in (!nCI!) do %@PrintMapped% !Ypos!;!Xpos! !Char! !C#[1]! !CharCount!
        Set /A Xpos=!random! %%!Console_Width! + 1,Ypos=!random! %%!Console_Hieght! + 1,Char=!random! %%79 + 1,nCI=!random! %%!CI#! + 1,CharCount=!random! %%5 + 1
        For %%B in (!nCI!) do %@PrintMapped% !Ypos!;!Xpos! !Char! !C#[2]! !CharCount!
        Set /A Xpos-=1,Ypos-=1,Char=!random! %%79 + 1,nCI=!random! %%!CI#! + 1,CharCount=!random! %%6 + 1
        For %%B in (!nCI!) do %@PrintMapped% !Ypos!;!Xpos! !Char! !C#[1]! !CharCount!
    )
Goto :4loop
```

Answer (score 1):

The 01 and 02 etc., change the color of the background. You need letters to change the color of the background. For example, `0` makes the background black and a makes the letters green, `0a` makes the letters green but the background black. A little chart from within a batch file may help. Here are the color codes:

- 0 = Black
- 8 = Gray1 = Blue
- 9 = Light Blue2 = Green
- A = Light Green3 = Aqua
- B = Light Aqua
- 4 = Red
- C = Light Red
- 5 = Purple
- D = Light Purple
- 6 = Yellow
- E = Light Yellow
- 7 = White
- F = Bright White