# Colored line code does not accept variables as colors

Tags: variables, batch-file, colors, cmd

I am coding a batch image viewer, set out of pixels which are shown on the screen with a actual way of colored words, lines or even just letters in the same line with different colors. Said that I am making a pixel type of a image viewer. The problem is that the code for coloring the lines that I found on stack overflow does not accept me to enter a variable instead of the color code(P.S. The variable contains the color code) while calling the command in code.
***This is the code for the actually command that let's me do color coding:***

```
:Echo.Color %1=Color %2=Str [%3=/n]
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str=%~2"
:Echo.Color.2
set "str=a%ECHO.DEL%!str:\=a%ECHO.DEL%\..\%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%!"
set "str=!str:/=a%ECHO.DEL%/..\%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%!"
set "str=!str:"=\"!"
pushd "%ECHO.DIR%"
findstr /p /r /a:%~1 "^^-" "!str!\..\!ECHO.FILE!" nul
popd
for /l %%n in (1,1,12) do if not "!ECHO.FILE:~%%n!"=="" <nul set /p "=%ECHO.DEL%"
<nul set /p "=%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%"
if not "%~3"=="" echo.
endlocal & goto :eof
:Echo.Color.Var %1=Color %2=StrVar [%3=/n]
if not defined %~2 goto :eof
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str=!%~2!"
goto :Echo.Color.2

:Echo.Color.Init
set "ECHO.COLOR=call :Echo.Color"
set "ECHO.DIR=%~dp0"
set "ECHO.FILE=%~nx0"
set "ECHO.FULL=%ECHO.DIR%%ECHO.FILE%"
for /F "tokens=1 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "ECHO.DEL=%%a"
goto :eof
```

***The command to display something is:***

```
call :Echo.Color E0 "a"
```

That will display the "a" letter in a yellow background and black font color.

***The actual thing I want to do is:***

```
call :Echo.Color %c1% "a"
```

The `%c1%`is actually set from a c1.txt file and it's contents are E0 which should produce the same result, just with the .txt file I get to make my own picture format kind of and then anyone could edit the file and make his own colored pixel which would make a picture.

**The solution to this answer is that someone gives me a different color code which I would not prefer, the smarter thing is to actually edit this code and somehow help me making the thing so it can use the variables. Or I have another solution of mine but I don't know will it work and how to get it to work. I could again echo out all of the commands with the variable and then save that into a text file(each one of them) and then load them back but I don't know how to use a variable as a actual command.**

Comment: Color script you found isn't working?  [There's a truckload of others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/) you can try.  ([This one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27322578/1683264) is my favorite.)

Comment: The truckload link you have actually put there is a link to the one I use. If I actually write something the color works perfectly, it just does not want to accept when I am using a variable instead of the color code, gonna test your favorite tho.

Comment: Thank you dude really much, I used the original jeb's method that was used in your favorite code. You could mind posting a normal answer if you want to so I could check it as solution.

Comment: I appreciate it, but the answer is so trivial S.O. just converts it to a comment anyway.

Comment: If you're talking about the script above, you never actually `set "ECHO.FILE=something"`.  The variable is empty.  If you intend to use `findstr` on a variable rather than a file, you need to pipe it.  `echo(!str! | findstr etc.`

Comment: Thank you dude for the help turns out I am dumb enough to forget to do cd.. out of the directory i was in and also turns out I forgot to use Load which is a command in my picture viewer to actually load all the variables anyways got it working now and at least the color coding script is simple and smaller now :D

Comment: If you are interested in a Batch image viewer that show pixels in color, I suggest you to see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-batch-file/23956113#23956113).

Comment: Thank you, but I have my own system and it is done now so yea....