# New color every line in command promt?

Tags: windows, batch-file, colors

I'm running a server that's started with a .bat file, and it's difficult to read one line of text from another as all one color. Is there something I can insert to have every new line of output automatically changed to a new, random color - different from the last?

Comment: Is this a Mac OS command prompt, a Linux command prompt, a Windows command prompt? Also, if you give the reason you are wanting to do this, it will help us answer the question.

Comment: Windows command prompt - and I'm running a server that's started with a .bat file. I was wondering of there was code I could Insert to do this, it's pretty hard to read as all one color right now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have multiple colors in a Windows batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: I usually invoke PowerShell when I want to output color.  `powershell "write-host 'This text is red.' -f red"`... or green, yellow, blue, magenta, etc.  See `powershell "help write-host"` for full syntax and a full list of supported color names.