# Coloring a single word in batch

Tags: batch-file

I make batch files and I want to make words colored by severity. Example: if the system detects a file that will be deleted if the program is not messed with it deletes the file so the word DELETED in the program would be red-the rest of the program would be the standard color.

Comment: You should add some example code.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have multiple colors in a Windows batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-windows-batch-file)