# how to change text color in a batch file after the selection?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to write a .bat file, which lets a person to choose from several different options.

```
 @echo off
 echo how are you doing today?
 :meniu
 echo Meniu
 echo ------------------------
 echo 1.Good
 echo 2.Bad
 choice/C:12 /N
 if errorlevel==255 goto error
 if errorlevel==1 goto good
 if errorlevel==2 goto bad
 :good
 echo have a nice day
 goto end
 :bad 
 echo i hope you'll get better soon
 goto end
 :end
```

When the user makes a choice, I want to change the text colour (lets say if choice is good, the text colour will be yellow, if bad - red). How do you change the text colour, starting after the input prompt, without changing the colour of what is already on the console?

Comment: you want to change the colors per line or for entire console?

Comment: Only the text that goes in the section :bad and :good to be in different colors

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4339649/2152082)

Comment: A very Robust Color option was written Carlos over on DosTips.com.  http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=41155#p41155

Comment: Your `if` queries will not work: either write `if %ErrorLevel%==1`, or use `if ErrorLevel 1` meaning *if ErrorLevel>=1*; if you go for the 2nd option, you will need to sort them in descending order...

Answer (score -1):

You can't change only certain colors, but you can do `cls` then `color [color]`. Also, instead of doing `choice/C:12 /N` you can do `set /p mood=` then do `if %mood% == 1 goto good` and `if %mood% == 2 goto bad` with `goto meniu` underneath it.