# How to keep the colors of text printed before the color comand in batch was executed

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to change the colors for the rest of the text promted by CMD and keep the colors for the text printed before color command was executed.

example:

```
@echo off
echo hello world
color 0A
```

The problem with this code is that it will turn the hello world text to green as well as all the other text in the command promt.

Comment: Are you ***really*** still using MS-DOS? (which would mean you are using `command.com` not `cmd.exe`)

Comment: Wait, no, [this one is better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-windows-batch-file). Regardless, this has been asked a bajillion times already.

Comment: No I am not still using MS-DOS, I am using cmd.exe, sorry if there was any  missunderstandings about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may *"change the colors for the rest of the text promted by CMD"* (that is *not* the same of "show text in a given color") with the aid of PowerShell, but the method is s-l-o-w...

```
@echo off

echo Standard color
call :SetColor Yellow/Blue
set /P "=Hello" < NUL
call :SetColor Magenta/DarkGreen
echo  World!
goto :EOF


:SetColor fore/back
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%a in ("%~1") do (
   PowerShell $host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = '%%b'; $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = '%%a'
)
exit /B
```

The colors set via this method are used in *all* posterior text displayed in the cmd.exe window!

Available color names:

```
Black           DarkGray
DarkBlue        Blue
DarkGreen       Green
DarkCyan        Cyan
DarkRed         Red
DarkMagenta     Magenta
DarkYellow      Yellow
Gray            White
```

Comment: This works as long as i dont double click the .bat file, if i put cmd /k in the end of the .bat file the cmd promt will stay open but all the colors will be changed to what i last told :SetColor to use.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you mean... This program change the colors of the text displayed _in the cmd.exe window_ where it is executed (exactly the same as `color` command). If the window is closed, ...

Comment: Yes, it works! I will accept this one as a working answer. One problem i have with it though is that it is not possible to double click this .bat file and keep it open. But that is another problem i guess. Thanks a lot for the help @Aacini

Answer (score 0):

This code can did the trick :

When you call something like this : `Call :Color 0B "Hello world !" 0`
The second argument equal to `0` means you stay in the same line

If you choose the second argument equal to `1` like this one :

`Call :Color 0e "Not in same line !" 1`

```
@echo off
Title Example with multicolors 
Call :Color 0A "Hello world !" 0
Call :Color 0D "Hello world in the same line !" 0
echo(
Call :Color 0C "Hello world !" 1 
Call :Color 0E "Not in same line !" 1 
Pause
::***********************************
:Color
for /F "delims=." %%a in ('"prompt $H. & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
set nL=%3
if not defined nL echo Requires third argument & Pause > nul & goto :Eof
if %3 == 0 (
    <nul set /p ".=%BS%">%2 & Findstr /V /A:%1 /R "^$" %2 nul & Del %2 2>&1
    goto :Eof
) else if %3 == 1 (
    echo %BS%>%2 & Findstr /V /A:%1 /R "^$" %2 nul & Del %2 2>&1
    goto :Eof
)
::***********************************
```