# How to colorize findstr output in cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, adb

In linux the grep output gets highlighted in red. Is there any special command to achieve the same using findstr in Windows cmd?

I am trying this command in cmd - 
`adb logcat -v time | findstr /a:color [4] \"NETWORK"` but in return it says `specify only /L or /R.`

(While Googling I learnt that /a is for color formatting and 4 stands for Red color)

I need to search for "NETWORK" calls my Android app is making. To view the logs better, it would be helpful if the output of findstr gets colorized.

Comment: Type `findstr /?` and see.

Comment: What happens when you only use '/a:04' and leave the string 'color' out ?

Comment: Remove the backslash in front of `"NETWORK"`; otherwise the opening `"` becomes part of the search string...

Comment: `findstr` does not colour its complete output, the `/A` switch is applied to preceding line numbers (`/N`) or file names (if multiple files are given) only; take a look at this great post to learn more: [How to have multiple colors in a Windows batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5344911)

Comment: Using `findstr` in Windows is like taking [a step back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman) to the DOS era. You're simply better off writing your own parser from scratch. Install Cygwin and be happy.

Answer (score 5):

The `/a` option lets you choose the color of the file/line number printed before matching lines, but can't be used to highlight the match in the text.

You can use the color attribute as follows `findstr /s /n /a:e /i "<your search string>" <file paths>`. Note that `/a:<color code>` is the option you are looking for. Here's an example:

[image: findstr with color example]

Here are the list of colors available. I am using 'e' or 'E' or 'Light Yellow':

[image: Colors available in cmd]

Comment: Well, but this behaves differently from grep. Grep is printing lines which contain the text you are searching for as `findstr` is doing but it's highlighting the searched text. `findstr` is kind of useless for me because without such highlighting, I have to manually read each line anyway and find where's the searched text.

Comment: To be clear, this is not the answer. Linux's `grep` command colorizes the matching string in output text whereas Windows' `findstr` command's `/a:<hexadecimal digit><hexadecimal digit>` flag only colorizes the output headings generated when the `/n` (line number) or `/s` (filename) flags are specified.

Comment: Misleading answer.

Comment: Happy to update if newer version of findstr supports highlighting the searched expression like grep. This is the best findstr could do as per my research when this was posted.

Comment: How is this not the answer, or how is it a misleading answer? The question was, "how to colorize findstr output in cmd?" The given answer clearly explains how to do just that, using `findstr` in `CMD` on Windows. No more and no less than that. Just like an apple is not a potato, you have to excuse `findstr` for not being `grep`.  Accept it for what it is. If you want `grep` then ask for a way to run `grep` on Windows. And learn to ask better questions! For example, "how to highlight string matches in output of findstr in cmd?" Then you get your preferred answer: it's not possible.