# How to write special characters in colored lines on batch

Tags: batch-file, text, colors, character

I am currently trying to make a simple choice RPG game that will have a lot of dialogue, and i want the dialogue to appear in different colors, but also share the same screen (like a chat room, if you will"), for a while, the code i've found in [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4oHz4DWpqg) has helped me a lot, but i quickly ran into a problem, i can't seem to write special characters like !?'*^<>,. and they are essential in dialogue, anyone knows of a way i can come around this problem? using "^" before each character didn't work, maybe changing the code would help?

```
@echo off
MODE 60,20
title Mage's Adventure 
color 0F
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
set "DEL=%%a"
)
goto :SplashScreen

:ColorText
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
goto :eof

:SplashScreen
cls
call :ColorText 0B "Welcome!, Welcome^!"
pause>nul
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  Could you write a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Here that would involve one line of code that you expect to print some dialogue with a special character, the output you're getting, and the output you expect.

Comment: Please edit the body of your question, and use [the appropriate formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: edited the post to include the code because i am still new here so i don't know how to add code on comments, sorry about that

Comment: It's good that you edited your post because you can't add code to comments.

Comment: @SomethingDark You can always comment on your own question, just not on others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get the ä, ç, or ã to print correctly using colorEcho in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307854/cant-get-the-%c3%a4-%c3%a7-or-%c3%a3-to-print-correctly-using-colorecho-in-batch)

Comment: @DanHall - I mean larges amount of code (anything over a single line) do not display properly in comments.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple solutions.

---

## carlos' color v23c

Playing around with it it has some strange outputs. Test using

```
call :color 04 "Test poison '&|<>!()" \n
call :color 06 ""
call :color 0A " can be printed if you use empty strings" \n
```

produced (german console):

```
">" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden.

" can be printed if you use empty strings
```

it produces some major errors sometimes and is a bit slow...

---

## VT100 alternative (Win10+)

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%E in ('forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(0x1B"') do (
    set "ESC=%%E["
)

call :vtEcho 93 "No escaping needed for most characters: '&|<>!()"
call :vtEcho 94 "Problems occur with '^' and '"' though"

:vtEcho   [VT100 colorcode] [message]
<NUL set /P "=%ESC%%1m%~2%ESC%0m"
echo+
exit /B 0
```

Output:

```
No escaping needed for most characters: '&|<>!()
Problems occur with '^^' and '"'
```

So how does this work? Basically echoing using `set /P` solves almost every poison character, and VT sequences make the color using the color codes. We first generate the `ESC` character using forfiles and then use it in the function. But since we try to give this as a single flag to a subroutine we need to double quote it... and that means we have problems displaying that. Also `set /P` can only print single `^` if you make it `<NUL set /P^"=^^"`, which will fail in any other case.

#### Workaround for `"` and `^` using flag shifting:

```
:vtEcho   [VT100 colorcode] [message] [message] [message] ...
:: Use """" for displaying a '"'
:: Use "^" for displaying a '^'
:: Use "\n" to make a new line
<NUL set /P "=%ESC%%1m"
:__vtEcho
shift
if not "%~1" == "" (
    if "%~1" == """" (
        <NUL set /P ^"="""^"
        goto __vtEcho
    )
    if "%~1" == "^^" (
        <NUL set /P ^"=^^"
        goto __vtEcho
    )
    if "%~1" == "\n" (
        echo+
        goto __vtEcho
    )
    <NUL set /P "=%~1"
    goto __vtEcho
)
echo %ESC%0m
exit /B 0
```

Test with:

```
call :vtEcho 96 "No problems with '" """" "' and '" "^" "' and has" \n "support for '\n'"`
```

result in:

```
No problems with '"' and '^' and has
support for '\n'
```

To compensate for `"` and `^` we check the individual parts of the flags if they are their wrong counterpart (`""` / `^^`) and print the right output instead.

#### HOWEVER

Using `set /P` makes it so you cannot start your line with spaces. To do this there is no nice wrapper function. If you dont need that you can use disappearing qoutes:

```
@echo off
set ""="
for /f "delims=" %%E in ('forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(0x1B"') do (
    set "BLUE=echo !"!%%E[94m"
    set "CYAN=echo !"!%%E[96m"
    set "END=%%E[0m"
)

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
%BLUE%Has no problems with '&|<>" characters%END%
%CYAN%'^^' and "^^!" need to be escaped%END%
```

Results in:

```
Has no problems with '&|<>" characters
'^' and "!" need to be escaped
```

---

I hope you are able to make something out of this. Thx for reading

---

**References:**

- [carlos' colorEcho v23c](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=41155#p41155)
- [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences - Text Formatting (Get color codes from here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#span-idtextformattingspanspan-idtextformattingspanspan-idtextformattingspantext-formatting)
- [Batch Snake by dbenham using VT100](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4741)
- [Info on disappearing quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7308647/9802724)