# How can I colorize the prompt string of Windows command line, as I do to PS1 of Linux?

Tags: cmd, ps1, cmder

EDIT:
This question already has an answer here:

https://superuser.com/questions/427820/how-to-change-only-the-prompt-color-of-the-windows-command-line/804458#804458

Please mark it as duplicate, thanks.

---

I know how to decorate `$PS1` in Linux, but I wonder if I can change the **color** of prompt string in Windows `cmd.exe`. I know there is a `$PROMPT` env var to change format, but I don't see any way to change its color.

I am using `cmder`. So if it is possible with tweaking this, it is OK.

I just want to decorate the prompt string, without change the color all the text in the console; it is to distinguish the output with the input line. Say, I have 300 lines of output, and when I scroll back, I cannot see from where I start.

I have posted another question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424166/differentiate-decorate-the-command-line-input-and-output-with-color-or-indentat), and made it in Linux. It is like this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have multiple colors in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: I agree that it is a duplicate, but of this question: https://superuser.com/questions/427820/how-to-change-only-the-prompt-color-of-the-windows-command-line/804458#804458

Comment: Can we redirect this question to the link that I provided? Thanks. The superuser.com one.

Comment: You could vote to close this question as off-topic and select better suitable on SuperUser; or you could flag it and ask for migration to SuperUser...

Comment: For duplicate another question must be on stackoverflow.com, so I voted as off-topic and move it to superuser.com, thanks for the tip @aschipfl! I didn't know that.