# How can I have color text output in a windows batch file that is called with the output being redirected to a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, colors, stdout

I am running a batch file with std output being redirected to a file and I want to get color text in the output that is being displayed on the console.  I have found something that gives the color text, but I can't figure out how to send it to the console. This works, but not when stdout is redirected:
[How to have multiple colors in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344911/1417694)

I call the batch file like this:
mybatch >myoutput.txt

My batch file looks like this:

```
:: Sample Batch file
@echo off
@echo this goes to the text file when std output is redirected
@echo this goes to the console >CON
call :ColorText 19 "This uses the above referenced method to print in blue, but doesn't go to the console" & echo( 
.
.
.
:ColorText
    <nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
    findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
    del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
    goto :eof
```

How can I get that text to go to the console?

Comment: What does `nul` on its own mean?

Comment: You need to put `goto :EOF` before `:ColorText`! What is variable `DEL` set to?

Comment: Not sure what the nul means, just did a copy/paste from the referenced link.

Comment: understand the goto :EOF... this is just sample code

Comment: You seem to have chosen to only use parts of the required code in Jeb's answer.

Comment: You have the answer in the line that is just right above the `call :ColorText`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `FindStr`, you could consider using `PowerShell` from your batch file:

```bat
PowerShell -NoProfile "'This is written to a file and also printed to the console in blue'|Add-Content 'output.log' -PassThru|Write-Host -ForegroundColor Blue"
```

It can be shortened a little by using aliases:

```bat
PowerShell -NoP "'This is written to a file and also printed to the console in blue'|AC 'output.log' -Pas|Write-Host -F Blue"
```

---

You can even specify the background color, [`-BackgroundColor`|`-B`] at the same time:

```bat
PowerShell -NoP "'This is written to a file and also printed to the console in blue with a yellow background'|AC 'output.log' -Pas|Write-Host -F Blue -B Yellow"
```

*The allowed colors are `Black`, `DarkBlue`, `DarkGreen`, `DarkCyan`, `DarkRed`, `DarkMagenta`, `DarkYellow`, `Gray`, `DarkGray`, `Blue`, `Green`, `Cyan`, `Red`, `Magenta`, `Yellow` and `White`*