# Colors In Batch File

Tags: batch-file, colors

I'm making a game, and i need different color bars. This code on GitHub actually makes the color bars with no ASCII but I can't understand it. Can anyone explain this to me?

```
@echo OFF
mode con cols=80 lines=25
color f
cls
echo.[47m           [43m           [46m           [42m           [45m           [41m           [44m           
echo.[47m           [43m           [46m           [42m           [45m           [41m           [44m           
echo.[47m           [43m           [46m           [42m           [45m           [41m           [44m           
echo.[47m           [43m           [46m           [42m           [45m           [41m           [44m           
echo.[47m           [43m           [46m           [42m           [45m           [41m           [44m           
echo.[47m           [43m           [46m           [42m           [45m           [41m           [44m           
echo.[47m           [43m           [46m           [42m           [45m           [41m           [44m           
echo.[47m           [43m           [46m           [42m           [45m           [41m           [44m           
echo.[47m           [43m           [46m           [42m           [45m           [41m           [44m           
echo.[47m           [43m           [46m           [42m           [45m           [41m           [44m           
echo.[47m           [43m           [46m           [42m           [45m           [41m           [44m           
echo.[47m           [43m           [46m           [42m           [45m           [41m           [44m           
echo.[47m           [43m           [46m           [42m           [45m           [41m           [44m           
echo.[47m           [43m           [46m           [42m           [45m           [41m           [44m           
echo.[47m           [43m           [46m           [42m           [45m           [41m           [44m           
echo.[47m           [43m           [46m           [42m           [45m           [41m           [44m           
echo.[44m           [40m           [45m           [43m           [46m           [40m           [47m           
echo.[44m           [40m           [45m           [43m           [46m           [40m           [47m           
echo.[44m           [40m           [45m           [43m           [46m           [40m           [47m
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: [robvanderwoude](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/ansi.php)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-windows-batch-file)