# Handy VCVARSALL wrapper

Tags: visual-studio, command-line

I have multiple Visual Studio versions installed (2010, 2012 and 2013 *for now*). Each comes with its on `VCVARSALL.BAT`. Whenever I want to target one of the environments I need to run the proper batch file.

Is there a handy wrapper that does accepts something like: `VCVARS 2010 x86` and runs the appropriate batch file? Writing one is simple, but I'd rather not do it if someone else already has.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a simple batch file that does this.

It can be found as a snippet [at Snippler](http://snipplr.com/view/94700/choose-a-visual-studio-toolset/)

Thanks to @VisualMagic for [colorEcho](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21666354/871910)

The batch file looks for Visual Studio in the default installation location on a 64-bit machine. I didn't need anything else. If someone does, the Visual Studio installation location can be found by following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/539680/226090)