# Code for changing colors in batch : How is it working?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I found [this piece of code which helps to change colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660249/how-do-i-make-one-particular-line-of-a-batch-file-a-different-color-then-the-oth/21666354#21666354) of text output in a batch file. Can someone please explain how it works?

Especially what is the use of `DEL` variable puzzles me, and without those first lines, the coloring doesn't work at all, but the `DEL` variable appears to be empty when I echo it.

```
@echo on
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)

call :ColorText 0b "red"
echo(
call :ColorText 19 "yellow"   
goto :eof

:ColorText
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
goto :eof
```

Also please shed some light on `for` loop and the `ColorText` method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)
```

After this block, the `DEL` variable contains a `<backspace><space><backspace>` string, created in the FOR loop by the `prompt $H`.
This works, as the command block for the for-loop is

```
prompt #$H#$E#
echo on 
for %%b in (1) do rem
```

This sets the prompt first to `#<BACKSPACE><SPACE><BACKSPACE>#<ESCAPE>#` (The escape is senseless here, I just copied it from my string library).
But normally the prompt wouldn't be visible, so I enable `ECHO ON` and then you need something that the prompt would appear and that will be done with the `for %%b in (1) do rem`.

The DEL character will be used later as file content.

```
:ColorText
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
```

The first line of this function creates a file with the content of the `DEL` variable.
The filename is named like the string you want to color.
This is important for the findstr command.

The `findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul` will be find any line by `/R "^$"`.
As two files are listed (nul is the second filename) each filename will be outputted and colored by the value of `/a:%1`.
As the file `NUL` has no content it will not be outputted at all.
And the first filename will be outputted also with a colon followed by the file content.

Sample, assume the file content is `ABC` and the filename is `Hello`

The output of findstr would be

```
Hello:ABC
```

But as I place the `<backspace><space><backspace>` into the file content the colon will be deleted.

The `del "%~2" > nul 2>&1` deletes the temporary file after all.

Comment: can you please explain with the flow of the program ? as in how are backspaces are generated and how the prompt part working , and why %%B (1) is used etc .. also how is ColorText method working ?

Comment: why have used `nul`  in `findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul` ? also what is the need of `/R "^$"` , will it find all the files present in the current working directory ?

Comment: also i still can't comprehend use of `prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem`

Comment: As explained, `/R "^$"` finds each line in a file (there is exactly one line). To understand the `prompt ...` just try it from an batch file

Comment: prompt `$H` gives `backspace` , `$E` gives escape code. but u said u will get <BACKSPACE><SPACE><BACKSPACE><ESCAPE> .. how ? also why u have used `#` ? and why have used nul in findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul ?

Comment: As written, you need two filenames, else findstr will not shown the filename at all, therefore I use as second file the always existing empty file `NUL`. prompt $H gives `<backspace><space><backspace>` the doku is wrong. The `#` is one chosen freely character as delimiter.

Comment: thnx ... what is the use of  `<nul` in <nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"  and why u have set value of `DEL` to `.` ?

Comment: The `<nul` is used as input for the `set /p`, else it would wait for user input. The `set ".=%DEL%"` simply outputs the `%DEL%` without a newline

Comment: one last question - You mentioned we need two file names for findstr else it won't  provide output. but i am still confused on why it wants to file names ?

Comment: With a single filename `findstr` works too, but it supresses the filename when it outputs matching lines