# Coloring specific parts of a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to colorize specific parts of my batch file and was wondering if it is A even possible and B if I can just color specific text and not the whole cmd window.

This is my test code in which I wish to color Y and N green and red:

```
@echo off
:start
echo hello, are you a Robot?
:choice
echo How do you answer?
set /P c=[Y/N]
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :start
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :shutdown
goto :choice
:shutdown
exit
```

Comment: Please check if this solves your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660249/how-do-i-make-one-particular-line-of-a-batch-file-a-different-color-then-the-oth

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make one particular line of a batch file a different color then the others?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660249/how-do-i-make-one-particular-line-of-a-batch-file-a-different-color-then-the-oth)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-windows-batch-file/5344911#5344911

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Call :init
:start
cls
Call :Color 0E " Hello, are you a Robot " 0 & echo|set /p="?"
echo(
:choice
Call :Color 0A " How do you answer " 0 & echo|set /p="?"
echo(
set /P c=[Y/N]
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :start
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :shutdown
goto :choice
:shutdown
exit

::*************************************************************************************
:init
prompt $g
for /F "delims=." %%a in ('"prompt $H. & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
exit /b
::*************************************************************************************
:color
set nL=%3
if not defined nL echo requires third argument & pause > nul & goto :eof
if %3 == 0 (
    <nul set /p ".=%bs%">%2 & findstr /v /a:%1 /r "^$" %2 nul & del %2 2>&1 & goto :eof
) else if %3 == 1 (
    echo %bs%>%2 & findstr /v /a:%1 /r "^$" %2 nul & del %2 2>&1 & goto :eof
)
exit /b
::*************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "esc="
SET "normal=%esc%[1;33m"
SET "red=%esc%[1;31m"
SET "green=%esc%[1;32m"
:start
echo hello, are you a Robot?
:choice
echo How do you answer?
set /P c=[%green%Y%normal%/%red%N%normal%]
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto start
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto shutdown
goto choice
:shutdown
```

My normal colour settings are yellow on black. The escape character is well- an escape, however it might be rendered on SO. I use `editplus`, which allows control characters to be entered. Other editors may allow this in other ways.

Other than that, it's simply a matter of switching the colours as desired and reverting to normal colours after showing the specials.

I've added a `setlocal` so that environment changes are reverted when the batch closes (this is for the general case; yours seems to be set up to `exit`)

I've also removed the colons in the `goto` statements. The only condition that colons are required here is the specific case of `goto :eof` which has a particular meaning.

Comment: Hmm - the rendering of an `escape` character appears to be a cloak of invisibility. There needs to be an actual `Esc` between the `esc=` and the `"`

Answer (score -2):

You can use ANSI [escape codes](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ansi.php) in batch files.

Comment: I guess you are down voted because link only answers won't suffice on the long term. Links tend to fluctuate leaving nothing to help others.

Comment: ... and also perhaps this is barely an "answer". It would be a good comment, though.