# Trailing whitespace in filename

Tags: batch-file, cmd, filesystems, whitespace, trailing

I tried using a batch-script from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21666354/4464653) answer to color some text in the console.

Unfortunately I had some unintended behaviour, using `´3 :s` as `string` for the call, which created a file named: "┬┤3 ", with a trailing whitespace.

Windows (10) (harddrive using NTFS) somehow can't handle a trailing whitespace in filenames, therefore I can't get rid of it.

---

I tried using `delete`, `rename`, `move` in the Windows Explorer and Total Commander - all failed.

Using the command prompt: `DEL`, `MOVE` and others results in a "cannot find"

Using `ATTRIB` outputs: "target of symbolic link "┬┤3 " does not exist"

---

To create such a file in you current directory:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do     rem"') do (
    set "DEL=%%a"
)
call :colorEcho 09 "´3 :s  `"
exit
:colorEcho
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Win32 File Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#Win32_File_Namespaces)

> For file I/O, the "\\?\" prefix to a path string tells the Windows APIs to disable all string parsing and to send the string that follows it straight to the file system.

To create the file in the batch script path:

```
> "\\?\%~dp0´3 :s " type nul
```

To remove:

```
del "\\?\%~dp0´3 "
```

The `:s` is a NTFS stream suffix which can be omitted for the task of deleting the file.

Comment: I did some testing with this - works great! However, the ":s" migth have a meaning for NTFS but is not processed with the "\\?\ prefix as it seems